# JavaScript && Operator used for returns

Tags: javascript

I am working understanding a JavaScript library and I came across this statement:

`const assetsManifest = process.env.webpackAssets && JSON.parse(process.env.webpackAssets)`

Then later on in the library, it uses the `assetsMannifest` like an object e.g.

`assetsManifest['/vendor.js']`

I thought the `&&` operator was only used to return `boolean` values in logical checks. Can someone explain to me what is going on here?

Many thanks,

Clement

Comment: The logical operators return a _truthy_ thing but doesn't return a boolean. E.g., `1 || false //1`,  `true && "a" //"a"`

Comment: Note that this is specific to some languages like Javascript that have a C-like syntax. Others with a very similar syntax (and the same operators) don't  behave this way and do indeed return just a boolean rather than the last evaluated value.

Comment: Logical operators are typically used with Boolean (logical) values. When they are, they return a Boolean value. However, the && and || operators actually return the value of one of the specified operands, so if these operators are used with non-Boolean values, they may return a non-Boolean value. check below link 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators . your case process.env.webpackAssets is object like String converted to object and accessed ''/vendor.js" key on the object

Comment: I think I get this now :) It's very weird compared to other languages, but it does mean less code, which is always a plus.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

&& returns first value converting to `false` or last value converting to `true`. It's because no need to calculate full logical condition with && if first value is `falsy`

```js
console.log(55 && 66);
console.log(0 && 77);
console.log(88 && 0);
```

Also you can use `&&` or `||` as `if` operator:

```
if (itsSunny) takeSunglasses();
```

equals to

```
itsSunny && takeSunglasses();
```

Answer (score 12):

This operator doesn't always return `true` or `false`. It doesn't work like in some other programming languages. In JavaScript `&&` operator returns the first value if it's *falsy* or the second one if not.

Examples:

`null && 5` returns `null` because `null` is *falsy*.

`"yeah yeah" && 0` returns `0` because every string is *truthy*.

Not so obvious :-)

Further reading:

[Why don't logical operators (&& and ||) always return a boolean result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417969/why-dont-logical-operators-and-always-return-a-boolean-result)

Comment: I found the link incredibly helpful. Especially the part where the `||` operator favors the first true value and the `&&` operator returns the most-right value provided everything before it was truthy

Answer (score 3):

in that context it is checking if `process.env.webpackAssets` is a truthy value. If it is it will evaluate and return the next part. in this case `JSON.parse(process.env.webpackAssets)`

The logic is essentially

```
if (process.env.webpackAssets) {
  return JSON.parse(process.env.webpackAssets)
}
else {
  return process.env.webpackAssets // (null | undefined | 0 | '' | false)
}
```

Comment: Or more precisely, `else return process.env.webpackAssets` - that value could also be `null` or `undefined`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Both `&&` and `||` are evaluting there arguments in lazy mode and return the last value, after witch the result is known.

```
123 && (0 || '' && 78) || 7 && 8 || [] && {} || 90 || 77 && 13

###_^^ both results are possible 123 && ???
        #_^^ first part is falsy, resume 0 || ??
             #####_^^ can't be true, return ''
          ^^_########## 0 || '' return ''
    ^^_################ return ''
#######################_^^ resume
                           #_^^ resume
                             ^^_# return 8
                        ^^_###### return 8
                                  ^^_########################## drop
```

And the result is 8.