# Under what circumstances is a className an Object?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have this:

```
const className = ev.target && ev.target.className;
```

in some cases `typeof classname === 'object'`...does anyone know why that's the case and when it might be the case? I always thought it must be a string.

I actually found a case where it's an object on the StackOverflow page, but I can't find the element again.

Comment: `classname` or `className`? We need a reproducible example. Generally, it’s never an object. Perhaps you meant `classList` which is always an object.

Comment: If **ev.target** is **null** then you will have an object in *className*.

Comment: I don't think `ev.target && ev.target.className` is the same as `(typeof ev.target !== undefined) ? ev.target.className : ''`, which is probably closer to what you intended.

Answer (score 2):

If *ev.target* is a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value, then the value of *ev.target.className* will be assigned to *className*, but if it was [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), the falsy value will be assigned.

For example, it *ev.target* is **null**, `typeof className` will return *object* since **null** is an object.

Answer (score -4):

You're assigning a Boolean value to the `className` variable. [Boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) is an object.

Comment: There’s no `Boolean` object in the code at all. `Boolean` itself is a function.

Comment: Doesn't `ev.target && ev.target.className` return the value `true` or `false`? I thought that would count as an instance of Boolean.

Comment: No, you have misunderstood the code. If *ev.target* is a [trythy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) then the value of *ev.target.className* will be assigned. If it is [Falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) the falsy value will be assigned.

Comment: [Why don't logical operators (&& and ||) always return a boolean result?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5417969/4642212)