# Why does the AND (&&) operator return an array instead of a boolean?

Tags: javascript, syntax, logical-operators

```
var array = props && props.children.find(ele => ele && ele.length);
```

The thing that is messing me up is the AND (`&&`). Shouldn’t the previous line of code return a boolean? I know it doesn’t because I have tried it, and it returns an array.

Could anybody explain what is happening here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why don't logical operators (&& and ||) always return a boolean result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417969/why-dont-logical-operators-and-always-return-a-boolean-result)

Comment: See [`logical operators`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) => `short-circuit evaluation` for more info.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The example you posted makes use of a few features of the JavaScript language:

- "Falsy"-ness: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy
- The short-circuiting nature of the `&&` and `||` operators: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation
- The `&&` and `||` operators return the "calculated value" instead of a `boolean` value: [Why don't logical operators (&& and ||) always return a boolean result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417969/why-dont-logical-operators-and-always-return-a-boolean-result)

It's semantically equivalent to this:

```
var array = undefined;
if( props /* is not null or undefined or empty-string */ ) {
    array = props.children.find( ele => ele && ele.length );
}
```

(Note the additional `&&` inside the `find` predicate, so in-full it becomes this):

```
var array = undefined;
if( props /* is not null or undefined or empty-string */ ) {
    array = props.children.find( function( ele ) {
        if( ele /* is not null or undefined or empty-string */ ) {
            return ele.length;
        }
        return undefined;
    } );
}
```

It can also be compared to the "Elvis operator" aka Safe-navigation operator from C#:

```
var array = props?.children.find( e => e?.length );
```

#### Explanation:

The `&&` operator evaluates its left operand first, in this case just `props` - if it is not falsy (not null, undefined or an empty string) then it evaluates the right operand (in this case, the `props.children.find` function invocation). Note that an empty array is not falsy.

If `props` were falsy, then the `.children.find` call would not be made, preventing a runtime error.

Comment: Really nice explanation and answer development.

Answer (score 2):

It's a way of checking to see if `props` is truthy before trying to delve deeper into its properties. If you simply did

```
var array = props.children.find(ele => ele && ele.length);
```

then if `props` was null, the line would generate an error. But if you know that props *might* be null and are OK with that, you can try to generate the array anyway, then when using it later, check to see if `array` is truthy before using it:

```
var array = props && props.children.find(ele => ele && ele.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, if props is defined the search its children for the first one that has an element with one or more nodes and assign it to `array`.

```
var array;
if (props) {
    array = props.children.find(ele => ele && ele.length);
}
```