# Split a text with header

Tags: javascript, parsing

I have a string like this:

```
&topic1
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, 
sed do 
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut 

&topic2
labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim 
www.example.com/test?id=1&name=abc
veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco lab

&topic3
hello
```

Each time there is `(beginning of line) + & + name + \n`, it should be parsed into a new item.

**How is the most natural way to parse it this way with Javascript:**

```
[['topic1', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,\nsed do\neiusmod tempor incididunt ut'],
 ['topic2', 'labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim\nwww.example.com/test?id=1&name=abc\nveniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco lab'],
 ['topic3', 'hello']]
```

**?**

I have several problems with this method:

```js
var s = "&topic1\nLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,\nsed do\neiusmod tempor incididunt ut\n\n&topic2\nlabore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim\nwww.example.com/test?id=1&name=abc\nveniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco lab\n\n&topic3\nhello";

s.split('&').forEach(function(elt) { console.log(elt.split('\n')[0], elt.split('\n').slice(1)); });
```

- the first item is empty (this can be removed after, but maybe there's a cleaner way?)
- if `&` is in the middle of a line (and not beginning) then this code doesn't work
- I'd like the the text after the header title to be in one single string (e.g. `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,\nsed do\neiusmod tempor incididunt ut`), and not split for each `\n`

How to do a cleaner parsing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split by linebreaks first, then join them up until you find a new topic:

```js
var s = "&topic1\nLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,\nsed do\neiusmod tempor incididunt ut\n\n&topic2\nlabore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim\nwww.example.com/test?id=1&name=abc\nveniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco lab\n\n&topic3\nhello";

const result = [];
let acc = [];

for(const line of s.split("\n")) {
  if(line[0] === "&") {
    // New topic found
    result.push(acc);
    acc = [line.substr(1), ""];
  } else {
    acc[1] += (acc[1] && "\n") + line;
  }
}

result.push(acc);
result.shift();   // removes the first element from an array and returns that removed element
console.log(result);
```

Comment: @basj i can't sorry (doesnt work on my phone), but feel free to edit :)

Comment: Wow, you write code on a phone, congratulations :) (I find it so hard to format code on such a small screen / small keyboard!). I edited into a code snippet. Thank you very much!

Comment: @basj its all about habits, thanks for the edit and im glad to help :)

Comment: A small corner case @JonasW.: if `var s = "&topic1\nLo\nrem\n&topic2\nipsum"`, then I would like `[["topic1", "Lo\nrem"], ["topic2", "ipsum"]]` and not `Lo\nrem\n` and not `ipsum\n`. Any idea? I should maybe remove the final `\n` but what would be the nicer way?

Comment: Looks great like this! What does  `s && "\n"` do? I know it for boolean but not for strings

Comment: @basj if `acc[1]` is an empty string ("") it will take that empty string (so it wont add a newline at the beginning) otherwise if `acc[1]` is not empty anymore, it takes `\n` instead, so it appends a newline then. This behaviour is called short-circuiting and truthyness.

Comment: Thanks @JonasW. for showing me && for strings! [Here is a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32158899/1422096) about it.