# HTML search text on load and alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to find a text on a loaded page and if the text matched then I should get alerted

```html
<script type='text/javascript'>
  window.onload = function() {

    if ((document.documentElement.textContent || document.documentElement.innerText).indexOf("John") > -1) {
      alert("Matched");
    }
  };
</script>


<body>
  <p> Hello! John is here </p>
</body>
```

Comment: So whats the issue with your code?

Comment: @user1531038 even if I remove the word "John" I still get alert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `||` operator to `&&` operator in your condition.

```
if ((document.documentElement.textContent && document.documentElement.innerText).indexOf("John") > -1) {
         alert("Matched!");
}
```

Comment: To improve this answer it would help if you explained why it works.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the || operation which means if any of the condition returns true it will be true. In your case, document.documentElement.textContent will be true, so it doesn't matter if `John` is there or not the if condition will be true, hence the alert.

Remember: In Javascript world: **Everything With a "Value" is True**

Answer (score 1):

Inside the if you check index of John in a boolean
Change the if condition to

```
document.documentElement.textContent.indexOf("John") > -1 || document.documentElement.innerText.indexOf("John") > -1
```

Answer (score 0):

You're essentially matching the string in your javascript. That is the "John" in `.indexOf("John")`

Your `||` returns the first not null item, in this case the `textContent` which **includes** `script` tags. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#Differences_from_innerText

Just use `innerText`.

```html
<script type='text/javascript'>
  window.onload = function() {

    if (document.documentElement.innerText.indexOf("John") > -1) {
      alert("Matched");
      console.log(document.documentElement.innerText);
      console.log(document.documentElement.textContent);
    }
  };
</script>


<body>
  <p> Hello! John is here </p>
</body>
```

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32158899/4665 for a good quick guide to what was going on with your `||` operator.  It also should illustrate why `&&` may not be the ideal fix.