# Javascript string validation issue

Tags: javascript, string, validation

I'm using the below function to do string validation:

```
isValidString = value => (value && value.trim() !== '');
```

I'm expecting a boolean return, but when `value = ''` return value is an empty string.

Can someone please explain why this is happening?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why don't logical operators (&& and ||) always return a boolean result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417969/why-dont-logical-operators-and-always-return-a-boolean-result)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

&& operator don't assign Boolean values but return value of last executed expression. for example in above method if you pass empty string then it return `value` as empty string equivalent to false. and if you pass non empty string then second part will return  `value.trim() !== ''` which is either true of false.

```js
    isValidString = value => !!(value && value.trim() !== '');
    console.log(isValidString(""))
    console.log(isValidString("a"))
```

Comment: `&& operator don't assign Boolean values but return value of last executed expression` - took some time but when understood made my day. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Strings with `length` 0 are evaluated as `false` in Boolean expressions in JavaScript, and since you are using the short circuit Boolean `AND` operator which stops further evaluation when it encounters a false value. Hence your expression returns an empty string as it caused your expression to evaluate to false.

Answer (score 0):

You could check if value is undefined using typeof value ! = 'undefined'

```
isValidString = value => typeof value != 'undefined' && value.trim() !== '';
```