# Why a = 0 || false returns false but not 0 in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Why  `a = 0 || false` returns `false` but not `0` in JavaScript?

Output from the debug console:

```
> a = 0 || false
false
> a
false
```

---

```
> a = 0
0
> a = a || false
false
> a
false
```

Comment: My guess is that since `0` is "falsey" `a || false` resolves to `false` (the latter clause of the `||`), which means you're setting `a` to `false`.

Comment: Yep. You are right David! Just thought about the same once posted the question. Thanks!

Comment: Why does your "output from debug console" not involve the expression you ask about in the title of your question?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417969/why-dont-logical-operators-and-always-return-a-boolean-result

Comment: Why do you expect it to return `0`? Did you read as `(a = 0) || false` (which still evaluates to `false`, but puts `0` in `a`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = 0 || false
```

Let's decompose it, or let's follow javascript's logic.

1. assign some expression to `a`
2. the expression is being evaluated
3. `||` tells us to pick first if it is *truthy*, otherwise pick second.
4. `0` is NOT truthy, then pick the second option, which is obviously `false`

Comment: That was the answer I was waiting for :-) Thanks for the simplicity and step-by-step details!

Comment: Have to wait for a few minutes to accept the answer. StackOverflow has 7 minutes limitation in place for this action :-)

Answer (score 1):

`a=0` is an assigment.

However, when you do `a=0 || false`, your expression converts to `0 || false`, the result of which is `false`.

Comment: `a = 0||false` is still an assignment!

Comment: yes, assignment of the value of the condition to the variable

Comment: What do you mean by "a condition"? The only expressions that I would call a condition are the first operand of the `? :` operator or what goes into an `if` head

Comment: if you did a `return a = 0|| false` , you'll be returned a `false` value. how is this an assignment?

Comment: It's still a return statement that contains an assignment expression

Comment: @AseemUpadhyay: I thought you were correct but your comments clarify that you're also missing a piece of the answer. In all cases, there is an assignment (`a=...`). Whether or not the code line _ends_ with an assignment, that's something else. But in both of your code lines (in the edit), an assignment is happening. I suspect you're reading `=` as if it were a `==`.

Comment: true, my mistake. i got confused a little bit. misalignment of words. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

`a = a` is no logical comparison but just an assign, so all you do is `0 = 0 || false` and since 0 is considered `false`

Why not `0` then ?
because a condition always returns a boolean so `0 -> false`

if you wanted to check if `a equals a` you'd have to write `a == a`

---

```js
a = 0;

console.log(a, a = a || false, a == a || false );
```

Comment: "Why not 0 then ? because a condition always returns a boolean so 0 -> false" `a = a || 0`

Comment: @tkausl it's not considered a condition anymore in this case. So it returns an integer because all values are integers

Comment: `a = a || false` when `a = 1` doesn't return a boolean either.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the last evaluated value for the operator `||` is the operand `false`. This is in keeping with short circuit evaluation for logical operator. If your expression were:

```
a = 0 || 22
```

The output would be `22`and not a boolean (`true` OR `false`). Explanation: same as above. The last evaluated expression is operand `22` and that is returned.

Let me know if that answered your question.

Ref: https://codeburst.io/javascript-what-is-short-circuit-evaluation-ff22b2f5608c