# Why typescript && returns string value instead of boolean

Tags: typescript

Why this code returns uri string value instead of boolean?

```
public getContext(): string | undefined {    
    return this.workspace && this.workspace.uri;
  }
```

This is the example https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-f75jhs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why don't logical operators (&& and ||) always return a boolean result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417969/why-dont-logical-operators-and-always-return-a-boolean-result)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is happening, because operators `&&` and `||` are short circuited (you can read more about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation))

What does that mean for your code above?

Let me try to explain it in a sequence of operations that are executed:

1. Evaluate the expression from the left of boolean operator `&&`, which is `this.workspace`;
2. If `this.workspace` is truthy then continue evaluating;
3. Evaluate the expression from the right of boolean operator `&&`, which is `this.workspace.uri`;
4. If `this.workspace.uri` is truthy then the whole expression is truthy and we can return what was on the right side of operator (in your case `this.workspace.uri`;

But, if the expression on the left-side is falsey and you are using boolean AND here, there is no sense in evaluating other expressions on the right, because the whole AND expression will be FALSE anyway. Hence, we can "short circuit".