# Expecting a Bool, Getting null

Tags: javascript

I have a function in a class

```
MyClass.prototype.IsFriend = function(){
    return (this.m_Object1 && !this.m_Object1.m_ABoolean && this.m_Object2);
};
```

`m_Object1` is an object in `MyClass`.

`m_ABoolean`  is a boolean within `m_Object1`, `true` or `false`.

`m_Object2` is another object in `MyClass`.

When this function should be returning `false` when `m_Object1` is `null` OR `m_ABoolean` is `true` OR `m_Object2` is null, it returns `null` instead.

Note: `m_Object1`, `m_ABoolean` and `m_Object2` are never `undefined`.

Why?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a reproducible example as a stack snippet?

Comment: The operator (`&&`) returns the value of the *first* falsy operand encountered when evaluating from left to right, or the value of the *last* operand if they are all truthy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The && operator return the first falsy value (the operand itself) it encounters, if it encounters null it will return null -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND

Comment: This is the answer, because it returns `null` when `m_Object1` is null. I never knew this. I always throught a logic statement with a load of `&&` would return a boolean. What is the recognised convention to use to get the funtion working as I want, maybe `return (!!this.m_Object1 && !this.m_Object1.m_ABoolean && !!this.m_Object2)`

Comment: @Rewind you could also just check for null values: `this.m_Object1 != null`.

Comment: Would `!!obj` be just as good to limit characters to minimize javascript file size?

Comment: @Rewind using !! will work in your use case

Comment: JavaScript curiosities: `!!{}` is true but `!!document.all` is false.  [reason](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)

Answer (score 1):

Logical operators in javascript return the first logically determined value from left to right,
For instance, `&&` operator returns the first value if it's falsy or the second one if not.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8569966/11414277) is a good read and the [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#logical_operators) is a good reference.

Answer (score 0):

I think that some of your values are null since:

```
true && null === null
```

Don't you have a way to check with debugger or with `console.log` the output of these values?

Comment: This answer is part answer part comment / request for details/clarification.