# ambiguous call ? javascript functions and objects

Tags: javascript, ambiguous-call

I see that in jQuery to be specific

```
var a= 'something' || function () {

}
```

or

```
var a = 'something' || { }
```

What does it mean? I know { } is an object json in javascript and am aware of anonymous functions in javascript but still cant figure out what does this means.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Please post a few lines of the real code; I'm pretty sure you misquoted it.

Comment: (a) `{}` is not JSON, it is an empty JavaScript object. (b) What is an *ambiguous* function? Do you mean anonymous?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does "options = options || {}" mean in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851404/what-does-options-options-mean-in-javascript)

Comment: This is quite common JavaScript short-hands.

Comment: actually i was thinking of ambiguous  and wanted to write anonymous so thanks for the correction :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You most likely included a faulty example. Your code *is* valid, but would be pretty useless to write, since you are assigning a known string to a variable, which renders the following `OR` statement useless.

What *is* common, is syntax like this:

```
function foo(bar) {
   // set baz to the contents of bar
   // or create an empty object if bar evaluates to false
    var baz = bar || {}; 
}
```

Comment: Agreed; in the example above, it looks like `'something'` is a string and this pattern wouldn't work because non-empty strings are never false.

Comment: Well correction your answer is the 1st answer i was wrong i got it all wrong thanks for the enlightenment :D i now understand what is happening in jQuery when they are using this slice of code thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

This sort of "conditional assignment" is a common idiom in languages which takes advantage of short-circuiting of boolean operators (like "OR" in this case) to assign to a variable the value of the left-hand expression if it evaluates to a "true" value or the right-hand expression if not.  Consider:

```
var nullOrFive = null || 5; // => 5
```

The left-hand side (`null || five`) evaluates left-to-right testing each operand to the OR operator until it finds a "truthful" one, returning it.  On the other hand:

```
var tenOrWhatever = 10 || someMethodThatIsNeverCalled(); // => 10
```

So in your examples, if "something" evaluates to true (which is anything but "undefined", "null", and zero in JavaScript), then the variable "a" will get its value, otherwise it gets the function (`function() {...}`) or object literal (`{}`).

Answer (score 1):

when assigning a value to a variable, JavaScript is evaluating the given expression.

```
var s= s || {};
```

this means that if there already is a variable named s in the current scope, the newly created s variable is pointing to it. Else, if s variable is not defined in the current scope, or it points to a null reference, or to some other value evaluated to FALSE, the newly created s variable will point to a new object. This is useful when one is extending one object in multiple files:

**File1**

```
var globalNamespace = globalNamespace  || {};
globalNamespace.someVariable  = "some value;"
```

**File2**

```
var globalNamespace = globalNamespace  || {};
globalNamespace.someFunction = function()
{
    return this.someVariable;
};
```

In this way, one can extend the globalNamespace object without having to worry that the code is spitted in multiple files.

Comment: this is also useful thank you guys i some times cant find a good explanation but this is it  :) i'd like to prompt both answers but i cant so this is an answer as well :D

Answer (score 0):

quoting the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) on MDC,

```
Logical OR (||)
expr1 || expr2
Returns expr1 if it can be converted to true; otherwise, returns expr2.
Thus, when used with Boolean values, || returns true if either operand is true;
if both are false, returns false.
```

Additionaly, there is a short-circuit evaluation :
    As logical expressions are evaluated left to right, they are tested for possible "short-circuit" evaluation using the following rules

so if expr1 can be evaluated to true, expr2 is not evaluated.

jQuery uses a lot of those short-circuit evaluation to define default values for variables. eg.
    var o = options || {}; 
    will put the options in variable o ; but will make sure o is initialized to {} if options is undefined or null