# Javascript 1 Liner Question

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does “options = options || {}” mean in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851404/what-does-options-options-mean-in-javascript)

What does the following line of Javascript code do?

```
var somevar = window.somevar || {};
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sets `somevar` to `window.somevar` if `window.somevar` exists and is not boolean `false`, otherwise it sets it to an empty object `{}`

It's a common idiom for handling variables which may not have been set.

Comment: Similar to a coalesce it seems

Comment: I was 'bout to go all ASCII art on this question, but English seems to be a better solution.

Comment: so by setting it to an empty object, does that in turn become available as window.somevar?

Comment: @VinnyD yes, if the context ('this') is the window, which is true for simple scripts running in a page

Answer (score 0):

It's an either/or assignment. If `window.somevar` is `false` or `undefined`, then `somevar` is set equal to `{}`. Otherwise it's set equal to `window.somevar`.

Answer (score 0):

This will evaluate the expression `window.somevar` as a boolean expression.  If it evaluates to `true` then it will return the value of `window.somevar`.  If it evaluates to `false` then it will return the empty object `{}`

Comment: Will it return the value of window.somevar or the reference?

Comment: @Ketan actually I'm not sure. Going to find out ...

Comment: @Ketan experiments indicate it's set to the value. Though I'm not 100% sure on this point

Comment: My experiment suggests it's set to the reference. http://jsfiddle.net/ft8d2/2/   Edit:@dgilland is right

Comment: It depends on what `window.somevar` is. If it's an object, then `somevar` will point to the same object that `window.somevar` points. So if you then modify a property of `window.somevar`, it will modify the corresponding property of `somevar`.

Comment: @Ketan that's because in your scenario you created and modified an object.  For simple values it uses the value (http://jsfiddle.net/RpvUp/).