# What does "var FOO = FOO || {}" (assign a variable or an empty object to that variable) mean in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, namespaces, variable-declaration, or-operator

Looking at an online source code I came across this at the top of several source files.

```
var FOO = FOO || {};
FOO.Bar = …;
```

But I have no idea what `|| {}` does.

I know `{}` is equal to `new Object()` and I think the `||` is for something like "if it already exists use its value else use the new object.

Why would I see this at the top of a source file?

Comment: Note: The question was edited to reflect that this is a code pattern commonly seen at the top of Javascript source files.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Your guess as to the intent of `|| {}` is pretty close.

This particular pattern when seen at the top of files is used to create a *namespace*, i.e. a named object under which functions and variables can be created without unduly polluting the global object.

The reason *why* it's used is so that if you have two (or more) files:

```
var MY_NAMESPACE = MY_NAMESPACE || {};
MY_NAMESPACE.func1 = {
}
```

and

```
var MY_NAMESPACE = MY_NAMESPACE || {};
MY_NAMESPACE.func2 = {
}
```

both of which share the same namespace it then doesn't matter in which order the two files are loaded, you still get `func1` and `func2` correctly defined within the `MY_NAMESPACE` object correctly.

The first file loaded will *create* the initial `MY_NAMESPACE` object, and any subsequently loaded file will *augment* the object.

Usefully, this also allows *asynchronous* loading of scripts that share the same namespace which can improve page loading times.  If the `<script>` tags have the `defer` attribute set you can't know in which order they'll be interpreted, so as described above this fixes that problem too.

Comment: This is exactly the case, there are a couple of js files with the exact same declaration at the beginning, thanks a lot!

Comment: +1 for reading between the lines and explaining the reasons for doing it. It's always good when someone gives the answer that the user actually *wanted* rather than just the one he asked for.  :)

Comment: i like to say it's the #ifndef/#define for javascript :)

Comment: `||` is also really useful when you want to provide optional arguments and initialize them to defaults if not provided: `function foo(arg1, optarg1, optarg2) { optarg1 = optarg1 || 'default value 1'; optarg2 = optart2 || 'defalt value 2';}`

Comment: @crazy2be that doesn't work if the default is truthy, but falsey values are also legal, since the `||` operator can't tell `undefined` from `falsey`.

Answer (score 25):

```
var AEROTWIST = AEROTWIST || {};
```

Basically this line is saying set the `AEROTWIST` variable to the value of the `AEROTWIST` variable, or set it to an empty object.

The double pipe `||` is an OR statement, and the second part of the OR is only executed if the first part returns false.

Therefore, if `AEROTWIST` already has a value, it will be kept as that value, but if it hasn't been set before, then it will be set as an empty object.

it's basically the same as saying this:

```
if(!AEROTWIST) {var AEROTWIST={};}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: actually the scope would be fine in your last example because _JS doesn't have block scope_

Comment: @Alnitak - meh, you're right; I've been working with closures too much lately and I've forgotten the basics. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 11):

There are two main parts that `var FOO = FOO || {};` covers.

**#1 Preventing overrides**

Imagine you have your code split over multiple files and your co-workers are also working on an Object called `FOO`. Then it could lead to the case that someone already defined `FOO` and assigned functionality to it (like a `skateboard` function). Then you would override it, if you were not checking if it already exists.

**Problematic case:**

```
// Definition of co-worker "Bart" in "bart.js"
var FOO = {};

FOO.skateboard = function() {
  alert('I like skateboarding!');
};

// Definition of co-worker "Homer" in "homer.js"
var FOO = {};

FOO.donut = function() {
  alert('I like donuts!');
};
```

In this case the `skateboard` function will be gone if you load the JavaScript file `homer.js` after `bart.js` in your HTML because Homer defines a new `FOO` object (and thus overrides the existing one from Bart) so it only knows about the `donut` function.

So you need to use `var FOO = FOO || {};` which means "FOO will be assigned to FOO (if it exists already) or a new blank object (if FOO does not exist already).

**Solution:**

```
var FOO = FOO || {};

// Definition of co-worker Bart in bart.js
FOO.skateboard = function() {
  alert('I like skateboarding!');
};

// Definition of co-worker Homer in homer.js
var FOO = FOO || {};

FOO.donut = function() {
  alert('I like donuts!');
};
```

Because Bart and Homer are now checking for the existence of `FOO` before they define their methods, you can load `bart.js` and `homer.js` in any order without overriding each other's methods (if they have different names). So you will always get a `FOO` object which has the methods `skateboard` and `donut` (Yay!).

**#2 Defining a new object**

If you've read through the first example then you already now what's the purpose of the `|| {}`.

Because if there is no existing `FOO` object then the OR-case will become active and creates a new object, so you can assign functions to it. Like:

```
var FOO = {};

FOO.skateboard = function() {
  alert('I like skateboarding!');
};
```

Answer (score 7):

Another common use for || is to set a default value for an undefined function parameter also:

```
function display(a) {
  a = a || 'default'; // here we set the default value of a to be 'default'
  console.log(a);
}

// we call display without providing a parameter
display(); // this will log 'default'
display('test'); // this will log 'test' to the console
```

The equivalent in other programming usually is:

```
function display(a = 'default') {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: You don't need `var` in front of `a`, `a` enters the function's execution context as a *formal parameter*, hence it is already declared.

Answer (score 3):

If there is no value in AEROTWIST or it is null or undefined the value assigned to the new AEROTWIST will be {} (a blank object)

Answer (score 1):

The `||` operator takes two values:

```
a || b
```

If a is [truthy](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/), it will return `a`. Otherwise, it will return `b`.

The falsy values are `null`, `undefined`, `0`, `""`, `NaN` and `false`. The truthy values are everything else.

So if `a` has not been set (is it `undefined`) it will return `b`.

Comment: I'm not sure *truthy* and *falsey* should be perpetuated as actual words.  Amusing, but not exactly standard. :-)

Comment: @Orbling they're quite commonly used to talk about such values in JS.

Comment: +1 for describe the operator correctly, since it isn't a logical operator. Sometimes it's called "default operator".

Comment: @Tim The only difference between `||` in JS (and Perl) and the version in C, C++ and Java is that JS doesn't cast the result to a boolean. It's still a logical operator.

Comment: @Alnitak: Possibly due to the non-professional background of JS developers in the past.

Comment: @Orbling Doug Crockford uses those terms.

Comment: @Altinak: His personal website title is also "Douglas Crockford's Wrrrld Wide Web" - I may not be deferring to him as a lexiographic authority anytime soon. ;-)

Comment: "Truthy" and "falsy" are also commonly used in the Python community. I find them shorthandy and would not hesitate to use them in discussions of other dynamically-typed languages.

Comment: @Orbling he may be no lexicographical authority, but I found your previous comment about "non-professional backgrounds" mildly offensive.

Comment: @kindall: Aye, the concept exists in most loosely-typed languages.  They are not bad concepts, I just find the words a bit lame.

Comment: @Altinak: Find it offensive if you will, it is nevertheless true for the most part.  There are expert programmers working in the JS field, yourself included no doubt, but the community has a far larger than average not so.  Anyhow, this is getting off topic.

Answer (score 0):

**For || operations**, JS will return the **FIRST** "truthy" value it finds (reading left-to-right):

```
var bob = false || undefined ||  0  ||  null || "hi"
//          ^          ^         ^      ^        ^
//          nope       nope      nope   nope     yip
//
// => bob = "hi"

// --------------
// breaking
// --------------
var bob = false || "hi" ||  0  ||  null || undefined
//          ^       ^
//          nope    yip <-- stops here
//                          the rest are ignored
//
// => bob = "hi"
```

Another trick is to use the && (and) to ensure something exists before accessing it.

**For && operations**, JS will return the **LAST** "truthy" value it finds (reading left-to-right).

For example if you're trying to read a property from a multi-level object.

```
var obj = {
        foo : {
            bar : "hi"
        }
    }

var bob = obj && obj.foo && obj.foo.bar;
//          ^        ^              ^
//          yip      yip            use this
//
// => bob = "hi"

// --------------
// breaking:
// --------------
var bob = obj && obj.foo && obj.foo.sally && obj.foo.bar;
//        ^          ^              ^
//        yip        yip            nope  <-- stops here, 
//                   ^                        and returns the last "yip"
//                   |                        the rest are ignored   |
//                   '-----------------------------------------------'
//
// => bob = obj.foo
```

Both || and && operations are read left-to-right... so you can have things that might normally throw errors toward the right side, since JS will simply stop reading left-to-right once it detects a truthy/falsey value.

Answer (score -1):

Notice that in some version of IE this code won't work as expected. Because the `var`, the variable is redefined *and* assigned so – if I recall correctly the issue – you'll end up to have always a new object. That should fix the issue:

```
var AEROTWIST;
AEROTWIST = AEROTWIST || {};
```