# I don't understand this code

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does "var FOO = FOO || {}" mean in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439579/what-does-var-foo-foo-mean-in-javascript)

I don't understand that :

```
var gapi = window.gapi||{};
```

Can you explain me? gapi is a bool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means if  the variable `gapi` exists already, and its value does not evaluate to a boolean false one, assign that to the variable `gapi` otherwise assign a new object to it.

This practice is helpful to avoid overwriting of variables.

These are the [JavaScript values that evaluate to boolean false](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Statements#if...else_Statement):

- `false`
- `undefined`
- `null`
- `0`
- `NaN`
- the empty string (`""`)

Comment: Ok thanks you but I duplicated the question....

Comment: Thus the difference between | and ||.  | is bitwise and || is value-oriented.   In the Cs  a || b is true if either is true but with a value unrelated to a and b.  In JS (perl, ...) a || b gives the first true value.

Comment: If `gapi` already exists and has a truthy value assign that...

Comment: @nnnnnn: Correct, if it has a value which does not evaluate to boolean false.

Answer (score 1):

The `logical or` stops if the first symbol evaluates to something different from a truly value, like, `false`, `undefined`, `null`, `''` or `0`.. Otherwise  it takes the second argument.

In this case, if `gapi` is not a global object defined in window, it assigns to gapi the new empty object `{}`.

Comment: No, `||` returns the first operand's value if it is truthy, otherwise it returns the second's. So please note that the second operand will be returned if the first operand has any of the falsy values `false`, `null`, `0` or an empty string (all of which are diferent to `undefined`).

Comment: @nnnnnn: Yes, you're right. I have not properly expressed.