# What it exactly means in Javascript (assigning variable)

Tags: javascript

I have question because I am not sure and cannot find answer on Stack Overflow about this.

What this exactly mean:

```
variable = variable || {}
```

or something that:

```
this.pointX = options.pointX || 6;
```

I understand that it assign to `variable` a `variable` if it **exist** or `empty Object` if variable doesn't exist but why it working that?

Is `||` not mean 'or' here?

Comment: This is basically "null coalescing" and you can find more about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476436/null-coalescing-operator-for-javascript and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439579/what-does-var-foo-foo-mean-in-javascript/6439629

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/6439629/643483

Comment: @Cory Like I said. I was looking for this answer but cannot find. Now I found many sources for answer to my question.

Comment: @Cory to be fair, if you don't know the term "null coalescing", it's hard to search for "javascript ||"

Comment: @jerry: Very true. I thought the links would help.

Comment: @jerry have right. I cannot write good title because I didn't know what it's called. Be placable.

Comment: @Cory Yes, that's a fair point. The first time I read it, it came across differently. Maybe it was prior to the edit or maybe I just misread it.

Comment: @Cory We can close this question, because now I found related topics. But while I writing question I still looking in related and cannot find these answers. EDIT: Can I vote to close my own question?

Comment: Yes, since you have more than 250 rep, you can [vote to close your own question.](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/view-close-votes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `||` is effectively working like a SQL `COALESCE` statement.

```
var x = y || z;
```

means:

if `y` evaluates to a "truthy" value, assign `y` to `x`.

if `y` evaluates to a "falsy" value, assign `z` to `x`.

See http://11heavens.com/falsy-and-truthy-in-javascript for more detail on "truthy/falsy" (or just [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript%20truthy%20falsy) it).

Answer (score 2):

The `||` is an `or` operator.

It basically means if `variable` is undefined, it will assign `variable` to a new object literal.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Logical_operators

Comment: `variable` is assigned to the second operand any time it has a truthiness value of `false`, not just if it's undefined. For instance, `var s = ""; s = s || "foo";` will result in s having the value `"foo"` even though it had already been defined.

Answer (score 1):

The `||`  operator returns the actual object that determines its "truthiness" value, not just a boolean (`true` or `false`). It "short circuits" in that once it can determine the result, it stops.

If `variable` has a truthiness value of `true`, it is returned (since when `true` is `or`ed with anything, the result is `true`). Otherwise, the second operand is returned (even if it has a truthiness value of `false`) since it determines the truthiness of the whole expression.

Answer (score 1):

`||` does mean OR here:

```
var x = 5
var x = x || {} //If v is defined, v = v, else v = {} (new, empty, object).
//x = 5 since x already was defined

var y = y || {}
//y = {} since y was undefined, the second part is run.
```

Answer (score -1):

```
this.pointX = options.pointX || 6;
```

Means assign `this.pointX` the value of `options.pointX` if available(i.e. not null) otherwise assign the value of `6`

Comment: pointX could well be 0, which is not truthy.

Comment: @DougM and I learnt that it can be also empty string, NaN, undefined

Answer (score -1):

The || operator in JavaScript differs from some other languages you'll find it in.  When JavaScript evaluates || it seems to return one operand OR the other.  It doesn't do a typical truth table evaluation evaluating to true if any operand evaluates to true, and false if not.