# I have some questions about javascript namespace

Tags: javascript, javascript-namespaces

I have run across some Javascript namespace definition. I am a little confused.

Below is a namespace definition correct?

```
 var googletag = googletag || {};
```

so when you add a square bracket in the end, what does that mean?

```
 googletag.cmd = googletag.cmd || [];
```

when you have a function defined after a namespace what does that mean?

```
var ctvAdManager = ctvAdManager || {};

(function () {
    var gads = document.createElement('script');
    gads.async = true;
    gads.type = 'text/javascript';
    var useSSL = 'https:' == document.location.protocol;
    gads.src = (useSSL ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
        '//www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js';
    var node = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    node.parentNode.insertBefore(gads, node);
})();
```

please advise

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does "var FOO = FOO || {}" mean in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439579/what-does-var-foo-foo-mean-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is shorthand `OR` notation. In english

```
var googletag = googletag || {};
```

Means: "set `googletag` equal to `googletag`, but if it is not defined, set `googletag` to an empty object.

`[]` is the same, just an empty array instead of an object.

The function notation you used

```
(function() { ... })(); is called an `Immediately Invoked Function Expression`.
```

I found this website explains it well. http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/

Answer (score 1):

The `[]` vs `{}` simply uses an Array vs an Object as the namespace.  The former will often work, but is almost always wrong; it pollutes the namespace with the Array prototype properties.  (`{}` does the same with the Object prototype properties, but there are far fewer of those -- and they are less likely to have desirable names.)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question, this function wrapped in parenthesis is a self-executing function. You can read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/440739/what-do-parentheses-surrounding-a-javascript-object-function-class-declaration-m).

Answer (score 0):

`var googletag = googletag || {};` will get the value of `googletag`, or, if `googletag` is not defined, it will take an empty object. 
Same for the second one, but instead of an object, will fallback to an empty array.
 For the function: 
`var foo = 5;

foo == 5 && doSomething(); // is the same thing as if (foo == 5) doSomething(); 
foo == 5 || doSomething(); // is the same thing as if (foo != 5) doSomething();`