# What's the meaning of var variableName = variableName || {};

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript from C++ background. I always see code like

```
var variableName = variableName || {};
```

It seems quite strange to me. Can somebody explain the meaning of the code? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're asking about how [logical operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Logical_operators) work.

Comment: **exact** duplicate of [What does “var FOO = FOO || {}” mean in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439579/what-does-var-foo-foo-mean-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means if that variable isn't set, make it to be a new empty object and if it is set, use the value of that variable. It equals to code:

```
var variableName;
if(!variableName){
    variableName = {};
}

var a = a || {}; // {}
var b = {"key":"value"};
var b = b || {}; // {"key":"value"}
```

Normally it's used to create a namespace to organize the code. For example,

```
var myNameSpace = myNameSpace || {};
myNameSpace.print= function(msg) {
    console.log("message is: "+msg);
}
myNameSpace.bar = function(){
    //do some thing
}
```

Comment: No, it is *not* equivalent to what you showed. Consider `var x = ""; var x = x || {};`

Comment: @IngoBürk: did you try `var x = ""; if (!x) x = {};`? It *is* equivalent as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Ingo, thanks for your comment, I've modified my code accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

That means, that if `variableName` is set, `variableName` should stay that value. Else, if it's not set, it should become an object (in this case an empty one).