# What does "variable || {}" in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I've seen some code in the form of:

```
var vendorcode = vendorcode || {};
```

I've always thought that `||` was a logical operator.  But this one is a real doozy.

Comment: See also [What does “var FOO = FOO || {}” mean in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439579/what-does-var-foo-foo-mean-in-javascript) for why this commonly appears at the top of JS files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This code assigns `{}` to `vendorcode` if `vendorcode` is `false`-y. 
Meaning it's `undefined`, `false`, `0`, `null`, etc.

If `vendorcode` is *not* `false`-y it'll keep its value.

You can read it out loud as: "`vendorcode` equals `vendorcode` OR `{}`"

Comment: I figure it had to do something with an assignment.  I didn't realize || could be used with an assignment of a function.