# Mix contents of 2 arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 array:

```
var arr1 = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4];
var arr2 = [];
```

`arr1` defines some groups, the group members are defined by the position.  So the group members `0` and `1` belong to group `1`,
member `2` belong to group `2`,
member `3` belong to group `3`,
the group member `4` and `5` belong to group `4`.

I would like to load the groups with their members into another array, so that I looks like:

```
arr2 = [[0,1], [2], [3], [4,5]];
```

So group `1` has the members `0` and `1` and so on...

When doing:

```
for(i=0; i<arr1.length; i++){
    arr2[arr1[i]] = i;
}
```

I get:

```
arr2 = [1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 5];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've almost gotten it right, but you need to create an array for each index in `arr2`, and then append `i` to it:

```
for(i=0; i<arr1.length; i++){
    arr2[arr1[i]] = arr2[arr1[i]] || [];  // create array here if none exists yet
    arr2[arr1[i]].push(i)                 // add i to array
}
```

Note that this produces an of-by-one difference from your desired solution (the first group will be at index `1`, rather than index `0` in your solution), so you can shift the indicies of `arr2` down by one:

```
for(i=0; i<arr1.length; i++){
    arr2[arr1[i]-1] = arr2[arr1[i]-1] || [];
    arr2[arr1[i]-1].push(i)
}
```

Note that you have not specified your desired behavior if there would be a gap in the `arr2` result. In this case, the index remains unset in the output array.

Comment: What does `||` mean in this context?

Comment: @user1170330 [What does “var FOO = FOO || {}” mean in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439579/what-does-var-foo-foo-mean-in-javascript) -- if the left side is "falsey" (`undefined`, `null`, empty string, `0`), then the expression evaluates to the right side -- in this case, a new empty array. Otherwise, it evaluates to the left side. So, it means "set `arr2[arr1[i]]` to itself, unless it doesn't have a value, in which case set it to an array"

Answer (score 1):

You need to create new array for each group and then push values to it. See my comments in code below:

```
var arr1 = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4];
var arr2 = [];

for(i=0; i<arr1.length; i++) {
    // array indexes begins from 0, therefore arr2[arr1[i] - 1]
    if (!arr2[arr1[i] - 1]) { // if array for this index does not exist
        // then initialize new empty array
        arr2[arr1[i] - 1] = [];
    }
    arr2[arr1[i] - 1].push(i); // push correct value to the array
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var i;  
var arr2 = [];
for(i=0; i<arr1.length; i++){
  arr2[arr1[i]-1] = arr2[arr1[i]-1] || [];
  arr2[arr1[i]-1].push(i);
}
```