# What is || operator in javascript

Tags: javascript, operators, or-operator

```
let x = process.argv[2] || "abc";
```

I am new to javascript. 
I don't think || is a boolean OR operator here.
What does this line mean? Why using OR on some strings?
Does this mean if process.argv[2] is null, then assign "abc" to x?

Comment: This is a boolean `or` gate. If the contents of `process.argv[2]` is falsy (`process.argv[2] == false`) then it will assign `"abc"` to x instead.

Comment: You inspired from this (asked few min ago) ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44885901/how-does-the-var-foo-foo-idiom-in-javascript-work

Comment: [Logical_operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Logical_operators)