# Javascript var = int || int?

Tags: javascript, web, integer

Little question, maybe it's a basic one .... but

What should be the value of ub ?

Suppose that getuploadedBytes return an Int, 
the value of ub should suppose to be what ?

The min or max value between method and right operator ?

```
ub = that._getUploadedBytes(jqXHR) || (ub + o.chunkSize);
```

Comment: `0` is a falsy int. [`||` is OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()). No idea where you got min/max from.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100758/javascript-or-variable-assignment-explanation, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439579/what-does-var-foo-foo-assign-a-variable-or-an-empty-object-to-that-va, and many other questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In summary, if `that._getUploadedBytes(jqXHR)` is **non-zero**, that value will be returned, otherwise `(ub + o.chunkSize)` is returned.

The || operator prefers the left value if it is truthy, and the right value otherwise.

Assuming that `that._getUploadedBytes(jqXHR)` returns an integer, then the only integer that is falsey is `0`.

Comment: Thank for the explication

Comment: A better explanation would be that `||` is a [short circuit logical operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation), and short circuit logical operators evaluate left to right returning the first truthy value encountered.

Comment: @TinyGiant: I'm curious as to your reasoning behind why it's a better explanation? Personally, I prefer the least-technical explanation that is accurate.

Answer (score 2):

The value will be the result of `_getUploadedBytes` unless that function returns 0, in which case it will be `ub + o.chunkSize`.

`0` is a falsy value, which means the condition will fail and the other calculation will produce the result.