# Where to find list of class IDs for photoshop jsx / extendscript

Tags: photoshop, extendscript

While learning about Photoshop scripting I found about the Action Manager, the ScriptListener Plug-In and how it can generate code based on your actions. Sergey Kritskiy was kind enough to help me with a proposed solution ([How to adjust the colors of a large number of images based on one spesific?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58226937/how-to-adjust-the-colors-of-a-large-number-of-images-based-on-one-spesific/58234678?noredirect=1#comment105258542_58234678)) but there are a lot of class IDs -which are used in charIDToTypeID(), that I do not understand (the code needs to be documented since it will go into my thesis). Strangely there is an index of all EventIDs in the photoshop-cc-javascript-ref-2019.pdf available at adobe help center but cannot find anything similar for class IDs. I googled quite a bit but cannot find anything of the sort. Am I doing something wrong?

For instance the following is the code generated for the filter > Stylize > Emboss (example taken from photoshop-cc-scripting-guide-2019.pdf -from adobe help center )

```
var idEmbs = charIDToTypeID( "Embs" );
var desc24 = new ActionDescriptor();
var idAngl = charIDToTypeID( "Angl" );
desc24.putInteger( idAngl, 135 );
var idHght = charIDToTypeID( "Hght" );
desc24.putInteger( idHght, 3 );
var idAmnt = charIDToTypeID( "Amnt" );
desc24.putInteger( idAmnt, 100 );
executeAction( idEmbs, desc24, DialogModes.NO );
```

The 'Embs' is an event Id, while 'Angl', 'Hght', 'Amnt' are class Ids. But while those are easy to guess others like 'Lctn, 'Mdpn', 'Opct' or '#Prc' are not (least to a novice like me)

Comment: What is a `class id`? I don’t think I heard this term

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy updated question with example

Answer (score 1):

Download the [Photoshop SDK](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/sdk.html). Inside you'll find some documentation in HTML format.

The key `Lctn`, for example, can be found in the full 'Adobe Photoshop SDK File List', inside PITerminology.h (to be fair, I had to use a File Search utility to locate it):

```
#define keyLocation   'Lctn'
```

In turn, where is this used then? There is some minimal guidance where these are used in `Photoshop Actions Guide.pdf'; it seems all of your abbreviations are function *arguments*.

`Lctn`, again for example, is used in `eventStroke`:

> Table 4–36: eventStroke Parameters (6)
>
> ```
> Key    Type    Bounds    Options
> keyWidth ('Wdth')    typeInteger   flagsSingleParameter
> keyLocation ('Lctn') typeStrokeLocation ('StrL')   flagsEnumeratedParameter
> keyOpacity ('Opct') unitFloat/unitPercent ('#Prc')   flagsEnumeratedParameter
> keyMode ('Md ') typeBlendMode ('BldM')   flagsEnumeratedParameter
> keyPreserveTransparency ('PrsT')   typeBoolean   flagsOptionalEnumeratedParameter
> keyUsing ('Usrs')   typeClass ('Type')   flagsOptionalSingleParameter
> ```

<sup>Yeah. This really is badly documented.</sup>