# explanation of "window.dataLayer || []"

Tags: javascript, google-datalayer

I am trying to understand what exactly:

```js
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
```

means in `gtag()` initialization as per [google instructions](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/devguides/datalayer?hl=en)

Does it assign `window.dataLayer` the object `window.dataLayer` or an empty array in case it does not exists?

Comment: `Does it assign window.dataLayer the object window.dataLayer or an empty array in case it does not exists?` Yes - exactly that. It uses JS's [falsy evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) to shortcut assignment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "var FOO = FOO || {}" (assign a variable or an empty object to that variable) mean in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439579/what-does-var-foo-foo-assign-a-variable-or-an-empty-object-to-that-va) or [What does the construct x = x || y mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802055/what-does-the-construct-x-x-y-mean)

Comment: _"Does it assign window.dataLayer the object window.dataLayer or an empty array in case it does not exists?"_ - yes, exactly that. The reason is that the Google script loads asynchronously, so the actual function object this will eventually be replaced with, might not exist already at the point, where you try to push to the data layer. This way, it still works. You are pushing to a plain array first - and when the Google script loads, it _replaces_ `window.dataLayer` with an object, that still has a `push` method.