# what does the "||" in a var statement mean?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [null coalescing operator for javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476436/null-coalescing-operator-for-javascript)
>   [What does “options = options || {}” mean in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851404/what-does-options-options-mean-in-javascript)

Can someone explain me this expression? I stumbled accros the javascript line of code and I wondered what it means.

```
var node = element.node || element[element.length - 1].node;
```

node get's used like this below:

```
if (node.nextSibling) {
            node.parentNode.insertBefore(this.node, node.nextSibling);
        } else {
            node.parentNode[appendChild](this.node);
        }
```

At first i though node should be a boolean or something but it's not.
Am I correct if i think that the meaning is: node is element.node but if the node attribute is  undefined node is the last element in the array of element?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your understanding is along the right lines; be aware that even if `element.node` is defined, but is a *falsey* value (`0`, `false` etc.) that `element[element.length - 1].node` will be assigned to `node` instead.

Answer (score 4):

It means, if `element.node` has a value represents True in boolean expressions, `node` will be `element.node`, otherwise it will be `element[element.length - 1].node`

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer: it means `OR` :)

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp

Comment: That part was quite obvious. The real question was: Was kind of weird "or" operation takes objects instead of boolean values and also returns an object instead of a boolean value? How is this "or" defined? Because it certainly isn't the standard definition according to logic.

Answer (score 1):

It means OR

for example:

```
if this || that
```

means "if this or that"

So when the computer comes to the "||" part of your code, if the statement before it is true, it will stop reading that if statement and automatically execute the code underneath.

If the item before that "||" is false, then it will check the next one, and so on...