# What does 'this.x1 = options.x1 || 0'; mean in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What does "options = options || {}" mean in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851404/what-does-options-options-mean-in-javascript)
>   [null coalescing operator for javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476436/null-coalescing-operator-for-javascript)

Was reading some code and I saw this:

`this.x1 = options.x1 || 0;`

Never seen syntax like this before. What does it mean?

Comment: My assumption is its short hand for "if options.x1 exists, this.x1=options.x1, else this.x1=0".

Comment: Every week or so we get this question in some form...

Comment: Thats because its damn near impossible to google

Comment: It should be mentioned that existing isn't the only criteria, the value should also evaluate to Boolean non-false. [See this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JimmySawczuk/CRGa6/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a coalesce... which means it'll assign 0 if options.x1 is falsy... and options.x1 otherwise.

Comment: you mean, if it has a *truthy* value.

Comment: Nope, not the way I said it. No.

Answer (score 2):

Let `this.x1` be the value of `options.x1` if `options.x1` has any *truthy* value. Otherwise let `this.x1` be `0`.