# Meaning of || in javascript argument

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does “options = options || {}” mean in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851404/what-does-options-options-mean-in-javascript)

What is the meaning of the || in the second argument?

```
   var obj = this;
   var settings = $.extend({
       param: 'defaultValue'
   }, options || {});
```

Also would be nice if anyone knows how to search that character("|") here or in google! Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100758/javascript-or-variable-assignment-explanation

Comment: To answer the last part of your question, you would want to search for "javascript logical or in assignment statement" or something similar.

Answer (score 9):

That would be the logical OR. The statement will return the first truth-y value it finds.

In this case, if `options` is null (or any other value that isn't truth-y) it will evaluate to false. The `||` will then return the empty object.

Comment: Here is the [**comprehensive list of what is falsy**](http://es5.github.com/#x9.2).

Comment: That isn't a logical OR though, is it?  Wouldn't the result of a logical OR return a boolean, not one of the values?  This is more like a null-coalesce IMO.

Comment: @StefanH No, it doesn't always return a boolean, it returns one of its operands.

Comment: @StefanH It's called OR because it's what it does when fed boolean values.

Comment: @StefanH - Oddly enough, no. Take a look at the documentation at MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

Comment: @phant0m I realize that in the situation above it doesn't resolve to a boolean.  That was kind of my point.

Comment: @JustinNiessner That makes sense - that is an aspect of Javascript's logical operators that I wasn't quite aware of.  Thanks!

Comment: @StefanH I only wanted to confirm your suspicions.

Answer (score 1):

That is some kind of fallback value or default value. So if the object is null or false the second value is used.

Answer (score 1):

More importantly in that scenario, if options is not defined then an empty object `{}` is passed as an argument. Its kind of a side-effect use case of the logical OR operator. More specifically, it uses short circuiting. For example in the below case

```
a || b
```

if `a` is true then b never gets executed, but if `a` is false then `b` gets executed. Hence in the example you have shown, if `options` is not defined and thus false, then `{}` gets executed and thus passed as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

|| = or

As in the comparison operator.

Answer (score 0):

`||` = "OR". Example:

`alert(false || false || false || "I'm valid!"); // alerts "I'm valid"`

In your question, the example above demonstrates that the function requires an object for it's options. In this case, if the local variable "options" is not available, then just pass an empty object. Later, in the function that's being called, it's probably setting default values in that new object.