# What does this line of code containing a '||' in JavaScript do?

Tags: javascript

I have read many javascript tutorials and I believe i know many things until now. So i thought that it will be a good idea to see a few script written in this language. My problem is that i don't know what this line really does:

```
var b=Number(ls.autofarm)||0,g,h,i,d,j;
```

I know the basics of these line, that the variable name is b and it has the value of Number(Is.autofarm)||0,g,h,i,j, but why are the "||" are using? It  will be great if someone could explain to me what this line does.

Comment: What makes you believe that is the correct value for b?

Comment: I suggest spending some time getting an understanding of the [logical operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Logical_operators).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does "options = options || {}" mean in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851404/what-does-options-options-mean-in-javascript) and potentially [many, many, many others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]+%22||%22).

Answer (score 3):

`||` in javascript is often used as a way to supply a default value. The first non-false value, or the last value found, "wins".

e.g.

```
var a = "foo";
var b = null;
var c = a || 2;   // c == "foo". a was non-false, so we use that
var d = b || 2;   // d == 2.  b was false (null, 0, "" are all false), so we moved along
```

in your case,

```
// b == Number(ls.autofarm), unless that's false/null/undefined. Then we use 0
var b = Number(ls.autofarm) || 0,
g,h,i,d,j;      // a bunch of other variables
```

Comment: Better to use the term "falsey" or something instead of "false" since technically `null` and some other values are not `false` but are "falsey".

Comment: Your answer is wrong. The variable `b` results in `j` if `Number(ls.autofarm)` is falsy. This is because the comma operator always returns the __last__ expression (i.e. `j` not `0`). Change that and I'll remove the downvote.

Comment: No, in this case the comma terminates a variable definition.  From the Chrome console:

    > j = "j was here"
    "j was here"
    > ls = { 'autofarm': false }
    Object {autofarm: false}
    > var b=Number(ls.autofarm)||0,g,h,i,d,j; 
    undefined
    > b
    0
    > j
    "j was here"

Comment: After some more thinking I realized that the variable `b` always results in `j`. This is because the comma operator always returns the __last__ expression (i.e. `j`) and has the lowest precedence.

Comment: Again, j isn't a value involved in b's initialization. It's the name of another variable being declared.

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
var b=Number(ls.autofarm)||0,g,h,i,d,j;
```

Can be split into two parts if it helps you understand.

```
var b = Number(ls.autofarm)||0;
var g,h,i,d,j;
```

The second line is a declaration of empty variables, while the first line is declaring b with a value. If the value to the left of the || is falsey, the value to the right is used. In this case, if Number(ls.autofarm) is false, b will be 0.

Comment: This is a good example of where the original snippet is a case of optimization over maintainability. I'm hoping that it is from some minimized script!

Comment: For sure, it's a good point to also remind people new to programming to *please* don't write code like this. :D  Although, it's a cool exercise in learning the rules of how the syntax works.

Answer (score 1):

`var b=Number(ls.autofarm)||0,g,h,i,d,j`;

Seems to me that b depends on the value of ls.autofarm OR is simply 0 (zero).

The other g,h,i,d,j; are decelerations of variables similar to

```
var b=Number(ls.autofarm)||0;
var g;
var h;
var i;
var d;
var j;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the relevant part (the other letters are just variable declarations):

`var b=Number(ls.autofarm)||0`

If `Number(ls.autofarm)` evaluates to `true` then it will be assigned to `b`. If it evaluates to `false` then 0 will be assigned to `b` instead.

Comment: Rather, if `Number(ls.autofarm)` is "truthy", it will be assigned to b.

Answer (score 0):

[**`||`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Logical_operators) is the logical OR operator, wich is also a *falsey coalscing operator* in JavaScript, wich means that it evaluates to the left-side of the expression if the value is not falsey, otherwise it evaluates to the right-side value.

Falsey values are: `false`, *empty string* `''`, `0`, `null`, `undefined` and `NaN`

The `||` is often used to supply default values.

```
function (someArg) {
    someArg = someArg || 'test'; // 'test' if someArg is falsey
}
```

When there are multiple `||` operators, here's how it evaluates:

```
var a = 0 || '' || true || false;
```

1. It first evaluates `0 || ''`, wich returns `''`
2. Then it evaluates `'' || true`, wich returns true
3. At this point, the expression will not be further evaluated and `true` will be returned.

Note that multiple variables can be declared and initialized with a single `var` statement, like in your example.

```
var b = Number(ls.autofarm) || 0, g, h, i, d, j;
```

The above initializes `b` to `Number(ls.autofarm) || 0` and declares the `g`, `h`, `i`, `d`, `j` variables.