# What is a purpose of 'var a = a || { b : 1}' syntax

Tags: javascript

I was wondering for a longer time what the below means:

```
var a = a || { b : 1 }
```

if 'a' had any properties assigned before... they dissapear. So what is a purpose of the above syntax ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851404/what-does-options-options-mean-in-javascript

Comment: if `a` is `false` / `undefined`, then a will equal `{b:1}`. It's really hard to tell what the original `purpose`of the code was. We didnt write it.

Comment: how this syntax is called? I didn't know how to search it.

Comment: Is this really valid? Can you evaluate `a` in it's initialization state like that? Just curious.

Comment: @OskarSzura https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+logical+or+assignment&oq=javascript+logical+or+assign&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l2j69i62l3.6559j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Id think it is - I can see it really often.

Comment: Yes I know it 'logical OR' but it this some kind of a design pattern ?

Comment: @Eric Its perfectly valid.

Comment: @OskarSzura It's called the `default pattern`. See https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+default+pattern&oq=javascript+defa&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0j69i57j5j69i62l2.2629j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @OskarSzura But I wouldn't get so hung up on if its a pattern or not. Its just something thats really nice to do, hence why you see it a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I love this kind of syntax. In my opinion, it is very elegant.

The explanation is fairly simple. What you have here is a conditional expression using the `||` (or) operator. This will assign a value to the variable according to the result of the conditional.

In this case, the condition is `a || { b : 1 }`, so if the variable `a` has already been defined (i.e. not equal to a false value), then the variable `a` will be left unchanged. However if `a` has not been defined yet, then it will be assigned the value of the object literal `{ b : 1 }`.

This method of syntax is usually used to define default values.

For example:

```
function say_hello( name ){
  var the_name = name || 'Dude';
  alert( "Hello, " + the_name );
}

say_hello( "Lix" ); // OUTPUTS: Hello, Lix
say_hello(); // OUTPUTS: Hello, Dude
```

If the argument `name` has not been passed to the function, the default name `Dude` will be used.

Comment: yup, I was taught once how to use this syntax for defaulting arrays say `arr[0] || arr[7]` on an array of size 3 will give the first element on array i.e. `arr[0]`

Comment: @rps - yep. That is indeed a valid usage of this method. However I would argue that the default value should be on the *index* before you access the array and not on the array access itself.

Comment: but how ? `arr[7]`  is falsy but `7` isn't.

Comment: I was thinking more on the lines of testing if the index is out of range first.

Comment: ah yes ofcourse, just for the fun of using _elegant_ codes one shouldn't skip the basics.

Answer (score 3):

if `a` is [falsy](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/) ie (false, 0, undefined, null, "", NaN) assign the default value `{ b : 1 }` to it

Answer (score 1):

The code assigns the object `{ b: 1 }` to `a` if `a` is undefined.

`a || { b: 1 }` means `a` or `{ b: 1 }` and the `||` operator returns the first operand which is true. So if `a` defined it will returned `a` otherwise it will return `{ b: 1 }` (since that is true).

Answer (score 0):

If `a` has some value already assigned then it will take that values else it will assign object `{b:1}` to `a`.