# Assignment syntax

Tags: javascript, syntax

I came across the following code on http://www.somethinghitme.com/2013/11/11/simple-2d-terrain-with-midpoint-displacement/.

```
function terrain(width, height, displace, roughness, seed) {
    var points = [],
        // Gives us a power of 2 based on our width
        power = Math.pow(2, Math.ceil(Math.log(width) / (Math.log(2)))),
        seed = seed || {
            s: height / 2 + (Math.random() * displace * 2) - displace,
            e: height / 2 + (Math.random() * displace * 2) - displace
        };

    // ...
}
```

I am unfamiliar with this syntax. What exactly does it achieve? What will the points variable contain after this assignment?

Comment: Are you talking about `seed = seed ||  {`

Comment: I'm guessing that's not the entire function, and that something is added to the array at some point ?

Comment: What exactly are you unfamiliar with?  How have you tried to research what you're unfamiliar with?

Comment: I think he is trying to research what he's unfamiliar with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following production is a [Variable Statement](http://es5.github.io/#x12.2), which allows multiple declarations to appear, separated by commas.

```
var points = [],
   // Gives us a power of 2 based on our width
   power = Math.pow(2, Math.ceil(Math.log(width) / (Math.log(2)))),
   seed = seed || {
        s: height / 2 + (Math.random() * displace * 2) - displace,
        e: height / 2 + (Math.random() * displace * 2) - displace
   };
```

It is treated the same as using individual variable statements, and the choice of which form to use is a stylistic preference. (I choose the latter, jslint suggests the former.)

```
var points = [];
var power = Math.pow(2, Math.ceil(Math.log(width) / (Math.log(2))));
var seed = seed || {
  s: height / 2 + (Math.random() * displace * 2) - displace,
  e: height / 2 + (Math.random() * displace * 2) - displace
};
```

The one interesting thing to note is `var seed = seed || ..`, where `seed` is already a parameter. This is because `var` does not "define" a variable, as in a language like C, but rather the declaration applies a scope-wide annotation. As such there is only *one* `seed` variable for the entire scope and `var`'ing it again makes no difference - it was, and always will be, a local variable.

See [What does "options = options || {}" mean in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851404/what-does-options-options-mean-in-javascript) for use of `seed || ..` in general.

Comment: Well, technically it *is* a declaration, according to the specification. It's just processed a bit differently

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks for keeping me on my toes.

Answer (score 0):

The points variable is an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're referring to `seed = seed || {` *object literal* `}`, the purpose is to provide a default value for `seed` in case the function was called without that parameter (or with undefined for that parameter, or any other *falsy* value).

If seed is present, it will have the value that was passed in, but if it is undefined (or null, 0, false, etc.), then an object will be supplied for it.