# What is the point of `foo = window.foo || {};` at the top of a Javascript file?

Tags: javascript

It turns out that there is a similar question, [What does “options = options || {}” mean in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2851404/664833), but that question is general - I am specifically asking about the occurrence of such a statement **at the top of a Javascript file**. I already understand that if `foo` is not already defined then it will be initialized with an empty object. Again, my question specifically asks about this usage as the first statement at the top of a Javascript file. Why would one do that? To prevent the object being overwritten by an assignment from a file loaded earlier? In the case I found, there are no files loaded earlier - hence my question:

**Question**: What is the point of `window.foo` in the following statement, which is the first statement **at the top of a Javascript file** (i.e. as opposed to just saying `foo = {};`)?

```
foo = window.foo || {};
```

Note that subsequent lines in the file define properties and methods:

```
foo.one = 'one';

foo.two = function() {
    return 1+1;
}
```

They are used as `foo.one;` and `foo.two();`

**(Follow-up) Question 2**: What is the advantage (and the difference in terminology) of the above approach compared to defining those very same things as follows:

```
var one = 'one';

function two() {
    return 1+1;
}
```

They are used as `one;` and `two();`

Additionally, all of the above are also accessible via `window`: `window.foo.one;` and `window.one;` and `window.foo.two();` and `window.two();`.

**(Follow-up) Question 3**: Is everything I define at the outermost scope bound to `window`? And what's the point of that? (i.e. What if it wasn't?)

Comment: Well, in the first case you have a controlled unique namespace. In the second case you're polluting the global scope, and you may cause conflicts with other libraries.

Comment: Ah, right. Polluting global scope.

Comment: Why do you post three questions per question? I think you've been here long enough to know better than that.

Comment: Regarding the duplicate question that everyone so ravenously jumped on, it's difficult to search the web for "window dot something at the top of a Javascript file". I obviously searched Google before asking here. Duh! And I asked a bunch of follow-up questions in one shot because I felt they were related to one another - if I knew more about Javascript, perhaps I could have asked them individually. Are you guys here to help or to feel empowered by down-voting and sneering at exceptional cases such as this? Don't you think my 4k reputation says I know the guidelines around here? Take it easy.

Comment: [\[javascript\] " || {}"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]+%22+||+{}%22) Your 4k rep certainly says you ought to.

Answer (score -1):

First question: If there is already a `foo` object, it won't be overwritten.

Second question: If you put things into `foo` instead of making new symbols, you avoid polluting the namespace.

Third question: Yes. If you run in a browser. That's called the "global scope". It has to go somewhere, right? If you don't want this, you have to make a new scope (via a function), or do namespacing (like with your `foo`).

Comment: You shouldn't answer duplicate questions

Comment: Just trying to help (and not afraid of the downvotes, I have been around long enough to remember when Stackoverflow was a friendlier place)

Comment: Stop crying. Your first two answers are poor. If you're going to answer easy, basic, oft-asked questions, at least put effort in to getting it right.

Comment: Thanks for your attempt to answer my questions. It's unfortunate that some folks were so quick to down-vote and get negative.

Comment: @cookiemonster: feel free to post your own answer or edit mine. I actually think my third answer is a bit poor. What's wrong with the first two?

Comment: If `foo` is any "falsey" value it will be overwritten. What are "new symbols"? What does "globbering" mean? What "namespace" are you referring to? Did you mean the global variable scope? Why would I post an answer to such a common duplicate?