# Setting Object with Ternary Notation

Tags: javascript

I only want to define an empty object `dct[dpid]` if does not already contain data.
This seems a bit clunky, is there a better way to write it?

```
dct = {}; //global scope
```

Later in a function with `dpid` defined as a string

```
dct[dpid] = typeof(dct[dpid])=="undefined" ? {} : dct[dpid];
```

Comment: You really should use a *hasOwnProperty* test since `dct[dpid]` may exist but have the value *undefined*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The logical OR operator is commonly used as shorthand](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2851404/218196):

```
dct[dpid] = dct[dpid] || {};
```

Though this only works correctly if the value of `dct[dpid]` can only be a truthy value. It would incorrectly overwrite `dct[dpid] = 0` for example. But if your property can hold different data *types*, then that's probably an indicator for poor design.

Comment: It's another object if it is set. Does that qualify as truthy?

Comment: Yes, all objects are truthy.

Comment: @AndyGee—yes. All objects evaluate to true (well, except null, but it's not *really* an object). Also beware host objects, they may seek to differ.

Comment: Works like a charm and looks great too

Comment: "But if your property can hold different data types, then that's probably an indicator for poor design." - I think the disclaimer about falsy values is still valid, as a general precaution: you could have `x[y] = x[y] || 1` and have it fail at `0`, with the perfectly good design of having all values numeric.

Comment: @Amadan: Yes of course. The statement is to be understood in this specific context, where the default value is supposed to be an object. If you'd work with numbers instead, you shouldn't use `||`.

Comment: @Amadan Point taken but for me at least it's going to be an object full of arrays of strings or undefined.

Comment: "If you'd work with numbers instead, you shouldn't use `||`" Meh... again, too much generalisation :) When you're counting frequencies, `x[y] = x[y] || 0` is perfectly reasonable. :D I'm mainly worried about people stumbling onto the question later, then taking away the wrong message (rather than, "know what your data contract is"). You already have an upvote from me, so I'm totally not disagreeing with you - this already works perfectly for OP. :)

Answer (score 0):

you could do:

```
dct = {};
dct[dpid] = (!!dct[dpid]) ? {} : dct[dpid];
```

or

```
dct[dpid] = dct[dpid] || {}; //defaults to empty object
```

Comment: You might as well just `dct[dpid] = dct[dpid] || {}`

Comment: Needs disclaimer: works great with a contract that you won't have falsy values. Breaks down if you allow `null` or `""` or `0` or `false` or `undefined`. EDIT: `NaN` too. Dangit.

Comment: What if `dct[dpid]` has some falsy value other than *undefined*? Like `null`, `0`, `NaN`, …

Comment: `!!x` and `x` are equivalent when in a condition; you don't need that.

Answer (score 0):

No need for ternary operator:

```
if (typeof(dct[dpid])=="undefined")
    dct[dpid] = {};
```

But why not just initialise it at the start?

```
dct = { dpid: {} };
```

Comment: a) using `dct.hasOwnProperty(dpid)` is safer than `typeof(dct[dpid])=="undefined"`; b) say you want to transform a list of edges into a dictionary of vertices to adjacent vertices; you don't know at the start how you'd construct it.