# Setting Javascript Variable, what does var win = window.dialogArguments || opener || parent || top; do?

Tags: javascript, variables

I came across this construction in a Javascript file, and I'm not sure what it does.

```
var win = window.dialogArguments || opener || parent || top;
```

I understand that `window.dialogArguments` returns optional arguments from the parent window, but I do not understand that the `||` operators are doing.

Is this setting up some sort of hierarchy, where if `.dialogArguments` returns NULL, it will assign the value of `window.opener` instead (and so on)?

Comment: Thanks everyone for answering so thoroughly (and quickly!)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does this construct (x = x || y) mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802055/what-does-this-construct-x-x-y-mean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`||` operator is the logical OR operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators). But its evaluation does not return a boolean value (*true*‍/‍*false*) but the first operand’s value that is identical to `true` when [converted to boolean](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-9.2) (i.e. `Boolean(op) === true`) or the second operand’s value otherwise.

So the expression `window.dialogArguments || opener || parent || top`, that is equivalent to `window.dialogArguments || (opener || (parent || top))`, will yield:

- the value of `window.dialogArguments` if its value converted to boolean equals `true`, or
- the value of `opener` if its value converted to boolean equals `true`, or
- the value of `parent` if its value converted to boolean equals `true`, or
- the value of `top` otherwise.

So it’s actually equivalent to:

```
var win;
if (window.dialogArguments) {
    win = window.dialogArguments;
} else if (opener) {
    win = opener;
} else if (parent) {
    win = parent;
} else {
    win = top;
}
```

Note that you might get a *ReferenceError* if the variable does not exist. If you’re in the global scope (`window`), better use `window.foo` instead of just `foo` to avoid such *ReferenceError*‍s.

By the way: Other languages have similar operations and functions that do nearly the same, e.g. SQL’s `coalesce` function that does return the first non-`NULL` value.

Comment: You may also want to mention that, in this case, the operator is used like the null coalescing operator in C# (taking advantage of the fact that both null and undefined evaluate to false when using the non-type specific logical operators in JavaScript).

Comment: Checking for truthiness is not the same as comparing to true.
('string' || 'other') evaluates to 'string' but ('string == true) is false!

Answer (score 0):

This is a clever method to find out the parent window or frame. It will return the first object in the chain that does not have a falsy value (i.e. `null` / `undefined` / `false`).

Read it as (argument1 **or** argument2 **or** argument3.....)

This is what it checks:

- `window.dialogArguments` will exist if a modal dialog was opened. [MDC docs on moda dialogs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.showModalDialog)
- `window.opener` will exist if it's a pop-up opened by `window.open` or (I think) a `target=_blank`. [MDC docs on window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open)
- `parent` will exist if the current page is a frame or iframe
- `top`  is the topmost frame in the frame set, but I can't see how this condition will ever be reached, because a `parent` should always exist. Maybe there are cross-domain issues if `parent` is in a different domain - I don't know for sure.

Comment: Thank you very much, this answer was also incredibly helpful!

Answer (score 0):

The `win` will be assigned to:

- `window.dialogArguments` if available first
- `opener` if previous condition not met
- `parent` if previous condition not met
- `top` if previous condition not met

*So `win` will be assigned to whatever is available **first** from left to right.*

Answer (score 0):

Yep,

it returns the first defined (*non-null*) object in the sequence..