# What does the || mean in this suitation?

Tags: javascript

Typically, || means or, but what does it mean in this case:

```
function getCharCount ( e,s ) {
    s = s || ",";
    return getInnerText(e).split(s).length;
}
```

Comment: Can someone please clarify. There are upvoted answers that say that if s is null then comma and another upvoted if s is null or "" then comma.

Comment: @Barry: it's because people love clicking arrows!  Raynos answer coupled with the comment is the most correct. Terminology wise, it ends up being a coalesce type operator instead of a logical or.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does this construct (x = x || y) mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802055/what-does-this-construct-x-x-y-mean)

Answer (score 10):

`s = s || ","`

It's the default parameter option. If `s` is "falsey" `s` will be set to `","`

So if s is an `""` or `undefined` it will have a useful default.

Comment: this would be complete if it listed `null`, `0`, `false`, and `NaN`

Comment: @Marc for brevity's sake I only listed the "falsey" values `s` is likely to have during normal use of the function

Comment: _during normal use of the function_  You don't know the same javascript devs I do!

Comment: @Marc I was making a _big_ assumption these devs were _sensible_

Answer (score 0):

That a way to define optional parameters in Javascript.

You can call this function with only 1 param...

Answer (score 0):

Raynos has provided the answer, but there is more to add to describing this.

```
s = s || ",";
```

If `s` is any falsey value such as `undefined, null, 0, false, NaN, ""`, etc..., then `s` will get initialized to be `","`.

This can be very useful for initializing optional parameters to a function or for guaranteeing that parameters have at least some initial value.  One does have to be very careful how it is used because this construct prohibits purposely passing a falsey value for the parameter `s`.

In this example, you can't pass an empty string for the value of `s` because it will be changed into `","`.  That's OK in this function, but maybe not in others.  In other types of functions, you wouldn't be able to pass `false` which might be an allowable value.

If one only wants to protect against the parameter not being passed, then you have to use something like this which explicitly tests for undefined and allows the passing of other falsey values:

```
s = typeof s != "undefined" ? s : ',';    // if s is undefined, initialize
```

or if you want to validate that it was a string and allow an empty string, you could use:

```
s = typeof s == "string" ? s : ',';       // if s not a string, initalize
```

Answer (score -1):

It means that s, if it's null, gets assigned the value ","; if s is not null, it retains its value.

Comment: This answer is just as correct as the others. Thanks for the unjustified downvotes, guys!

Answer (score -1):

`s` is `s`, or if `s` is not defined ( you did not pass the argument in the function call ), it's `","`

Comment: Any value of s that is falsey (undefined, false, 0, "", null, ...) will trigger the assignment of the comma string, not just undefined.  I didn't downvote, but wanted to explain what was missing from your answer.

Comment: If you wanted the statement to trigger only when s was undefined, it would have to be something like this:  `s = typeof s != "undefined" ? s : ',';`

Answer (score -1):

sometimes , you dont know if a variable will ahve a value
so you are telling your self that you have to have a value.

if if theres no value ( null) so youll have your own default value.

that what you wrote

```
 s = s || ",";
```

i dont know if s has value or not , but if not so put the ',' value.