# javascript: || (or) in variable define?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does this construct (x = x || y) mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802055/what-does-this-construct-x-x-y-mean)

a lot of times i can see that variables set like that

```
var d = d || {}
```

or

```
var = var || []
```

a few question came up to mind

1. what it's mainly purpose ?
2. how can it be to use OR in variable define?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `||` operator returns the left hand side if it is true and the right hand side if the left hand side isn't true.

So:

```
var d = d || {}
```

Is a quick way of saying:

```
var d;
if (!d) {
    d = {};
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that `var d = d || {}` will always assign a value to `d`, even it' the current value (although it's possible this could be optimized by a smart engine); in the case of `obj.x = obj.x || foo` this cannot be optimized in the face of custom getters/setters, but that's a different story ... somewhat.

Answer (score 3):

If the left hand side is *falsy* (such as `undefined`, which a function argument is if it is not passed), it evaluates the right hand side. The last side to evaluate is returned in JavaScript, unlike some languages which return *true* or *false*. This is handy and why this construct is used.

It exploits [short circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

The main reason it is used is to provide a sensible default if a parameter to a function is not passed.

```
var a = function(b) {
    b = b || [];
}
```

In the previous code example, if `b` was not passed, it is defaulted to a blank array (`[]`). However, if I passed `0` or something else *falsy*, it would become a blank array too. Be careful with this.

Comment: @pst I made `Array` a code sample as it is a constructor for an array, and an actual type/object in the language.

Comment: Yes, this construct is common and handy, but it can bite you when `0`, `false` and the empty string are legitimate values for the given context.

Comment: @alex Wonder if it was SO's wonderful lack of optimistic concurrency again... I was just trying to format the larger code-block.