# Use the || operator notice

Tags: javascript, netbeans, use-strict

Javascript code:

```
var a = (b) ? b : 40;
```

It is working, just NetBeans says: "Use the || operator (Column [where the ? is])". I didn't find any explanation.

What is it?

Thanks!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802055/what-does-this-construct-x-x-y-mean

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are just testing for the truthyness of `b` then you can do this:

```
var a = b || 40;
```

… which is shorter and (arguably) more obvious. In JavaScript, `||` is a short circuit operator. It returns the left hand side if it is true, otherwise it returns the right hand side. (i.e. it doesn't return a boolean unless the input was a boolean).

If you want to see if `b` is actually defined, then you are better off with:

```
var a = (typeof b !== "undefined") ? b : 40;
```

Comment: @GáborVarga — I have absolutely no idea what you are asking.

Answer (score 3):

The pipes are the `or` statement. `var a = b || 40` says if b is non-falsey value, let a=b, otherwise 40.