# what does "object || {} " means in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

I found below line of code in javascript application.

```
var auth = parent.auth = parent.auth || {};
```

I know there is existing Object parent which is extended with auth Object but i don't understand what is `parent.auth || {}` doing here.

Comment: `var newVar = false || null || true` will assign `true` to `newVar`. the logical or operator is used to prevent _falsy_ values from being assigned. If `parent.auth` is falsy, or doesn't exist, then a new object literal is assigned

Comment: Related: [What does the construct x = x || y mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802055/what-does-the-construct-x-x-y-mean/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`parent.auth || {}` means if `parent.auth` is undefined, null or false in boolean case then new empty object will be initialized and assigned.

or you can understand it like:

```
var auth;
if(parent.auth){       
    auth=parent.auth;   
} else {
    auth={};   
}
```

Comment: @sp00m the second approach explains the same. CLEARLY!!

Comment: @Mr_Green What to you mean? I just wanted to add that 0, "" or NaN will be evaluated to false (i.e. falsy) as well as null, false or undefined.

Comment: @sp00m the caps letter in my above comment means it is very clear that this six types falsies will be evaluated to false but not as I am shouting at you. :)

Answer (score 3):

it means if the value of `parent.auth` is falsy(false, 0, null, undefied etc) then assign the value `{}`(empty object) to the variable `auth`

Comment: but why parent.auth is assigned two times

Comment: @Sandeepvashisth it is because the `parent.auth`'s value itself is updated with the empty object if it is a falsy value... so once the statement is executed `parent.auth` will have a non falsy value

Comment: @Sandeepvashisth Maybe reading about [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) helps to understand this better?

Answer (score 0):

|| is or, the code then returns an empty object, if parent.auth is undefined.

Like checking for null, then creating a new object if null (from java/c#).