# What does 'options || (options = {})' do?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to better understand [BackboneJS](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html) by reading the annotated source.

```
options || (options = {});
```

Options is an attribute passed into a function, so presumably could be 'undefined'. My initial thoughts were that this statement would set options to an empty object if it was undefined. However my experimenting seemed to tell me this is not the case. Also, the previous line is this:

```
var attrs = attributes || {};
```

Which I believe does pretty much what I'd described (whilst also shortening the attribute name).

My question is, what is the actual purpose of the first code snippet?

Full context is [here](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-32)

Comment: `options || (options = {});` is the same as `options = options || {};`. Just make it an empty object if undefined

Comment: [see here for answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24282165/821057)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
   options || (options = {});
```

Checks if `options` is undefined. If it is then it it assigns a new object value to `options`.

After the line occurs:

1.`options` will not be undefined.
 2.The left hand sign(if exists) will be assigned with options.

This is the same as

`options = options || {};`

This line:

```
var attrs = attributes || {};
```

assigns the `attributes` value to `attrs` if `attributes` is not undefined and if it is, it assigns a new object to `attrs`. similiar to:

```
var attrs;
if(attributes)
   attrs = attributes;
else
  attrs = {};
```

Answer (score 1):

The statement:

```
options || (options = {});
```

Is a shorthand for:

```
if(!options) {
    options = {};
}
```

And it is faster compared to the equivalent shorthand:

```
options = options || {};
```