# how to invoke a plugin with slightly different behaviour?

Tags: jquery, plugins

I have a simple plugin which has init, close and open functions in it. I have an array of html templates which invoke this plugin. Only for certain template, I want to do slightly different behavior to this plugin, lets say add a different class in the open function and remove the same class when closed. What is an elegant way of doing it? Should I find the id of the html and do an if else within the open and close functions within the same plugin or is there a better way to do it?

```
;(function ($, window, document, undefined) {

    function Plugin(element, options) {
            Window = this;
            this.element = element;
            this._name = pluginName;
            this.init(element);
        }

    Plugin.prototype = {
            init: function(element) {
     },
    close:function(e){
    //removes a class and hides the element
    },
    open:function(element){
    //adds a class and shows the element
    }

    }
//Extend Global jQuery (where we actually add the plugin!)
    $.fn[pluginName] = function (options) {
        plugin = $.data(window, 'plugin_' + pluginName);
        if (!(plugin instanceof Plugin)) {
            $.data(window, 'plugin_' + pluginName,
            plugin = new Plugin( this, options ));
        }
        return $Extend(this).each(function () {
            $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName, plugin);
        });
    };

}(jQuery, window, document));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would handle initialization settings by added an optional object to your `options` param that you pass into the plugin.

Essentially, just make sure the `options` param is accessible to all relevant initialization methods, then do something like the followings:

```
open: function(element){
var initClass = options.initClass || "DEFAULTVALUE";
 //adds "initClass" as a class and show the element
}
```

The || is a shorthand trick that says if "options.initClass" doesn't exist, default the next value. You can learn more about || [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2802064/1538708).

Comment: Or use the `extend()` idiom that's used in most jQuery plugins to merge the user's options into a default options object.

Comment: The other thing you have to do is remember the options used for each element. This can be done using `data()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a set of options:

```
MyPlugin.options = {
    width: 200,
    height: 500,
    add: function () { 
        alert("add was called"); 
    },
    delete: function () { 
        alert("delete was called");
    }
};
```

When you pass options into your Plugin you could override the defaults:

```
function MyPlugin(options){
    options = $.extend({}, MyPlugin.options, options);

    options.add();
}
```

Whenever you create an instance of your plugin you can then override one or more properties by setting its options:

```
var plugin = new MyPlugin({
    width: 100,
    add: function () {
        alert("My add was called!");
    }
});
```

In the previous code, an alert would display showing "My add was called!".