# JavaScript: Array push method

Tags: javascript

Considering text as an array variable, please explain the push method statement shown below:

```
var text = [];
text.push(document.getElementById('name').innerHTML || 0);
```

Comment: Add the innerHTML string or 0 to the end of the array ...

Comment: What do you need explained? Did you try it in the developer console?

Comment: Copy-pasted exam question?

Comment: I am new to JavaScript and my confusion is only with '|| 0' part in that statement. I mean what is the purpose of adding this part along with document.getElementById('name').innerHTML?

Comment: @Jan: No, it's not copy pasted. Actually I was studying some script and come across such a statement. As I said, I am new to JS and have seen push method with only one value so far....

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802055/what-does-this-construct-x-x-y-mean

Comment: @user1934643 your code is also about pushing ONE value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is that an empty string is evaluated as false in boolean tests like this.

Example :

```
var a = "" || 0;          // a is set to 0 because "" is empty and is false
var b = "non-empty" || 0  // b is set to "non-empty" because it's not an empty string
```

Comment: Thank so much climbage, though I was also guessing the same but was doubtful so wanted to get it confirmed with experts as I have never seen such an expression before....Once again a big thanks to you for making me clear on this :-)

Comment: Technically, `""` is falsy, not false

Comment: @user1934643 Okay, I kinda regret my close vote now (too late, I know). Just FYI, this kind of use of `||` is called "short-circuit boolean evaluation". See the question linked as possible duplicate in the comments above.

Comment: @bfavaretto it's never too late to retract a close vote. We have a thing called "reopen votes". However, if this gets reopened, the next step will be to close this as a duplicate.

Comment: @JanDvorak In this particular case, I regret the close vote *reason* (I'd prefer "dupe", but couldn't find a good one and voted for "too localized"). So I won't vote to reopen just to have it closed again.

Answer (score 0):

it will add HTML content of dom element with id='name' if it's not empty to text array , otherwise it will add 0 to it

Comment: Thank you for your input dear and making me clear on this.....