# Code is heuristically unreachable assigning null to variable if string is null

Tags: javascript, resharper

Simple question:

```
var x = '<%=Request["myvar"]%>' || null;
```

why does resharper say "Code is heuristically unreachable",
When this seems to work just fine?

Comment: so how come it works? if there is a query parameter, it return the query parameter, if there isnt, it returns null. so it does not always short circuit, does it?

Comment: I think the `|| null` is unreachable, not the request variable. It will always resolve to at least an empty string.

Comment: "if there isnt, it returns null." - without wanting to sound patronising, are you talking about `"null"` or `null`, which are different?

Comment: it returns 'null' not "null", which i find strange by what was said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting `x` to a string value so it will never equal `null`. Therefore the `|| null` is unreachable.

This should help:
[What does the construct x = x || y mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802055/what-does-this-construct-x-x-y-mean)

Comment: as per my comment, if the string is empty, i do get null. if it was unreachable, why do i get the null result when the string is empty?