# Javascript: meaning of || operator while initializing var

Tags: javascript, keypress, operator-keyword

to get information about what key was pressed, I now use following code:

```
function AddEventListeners() {
    document.getElementById('txtHangman').addEventListener('keypress', TextHangman.bind(this), false);
}
```

And then the eventhandler function:

```
function TextHangman(_key) {
    var _keypressed = _key.which || _key.key;
}
```

The code works and gives me the information I want but I don't understand what the || operator does when initiliazing the var _keypressed. Some explanation would be great.

Thanks!

G

Comment: dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802055/what-does-this-construct-x-x-y-mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means the same as it does everywhere else. It does nothing special when used near a `var` statement.

If the left hand side evaluates as true (i.e. not `0`, `undefined`, etc), it evaluates as the left hand side.

Otherwise, it evaluates as the right hand side.

---

Precedence rules means it gets resolved before the assignment.

---

Essentially the code is the same as:

```
if (_key.which) {
    var _keypressed = _key.which;
} else {
    var _keypressed = _key.key;
}
```

Comment: The list of falsy values are available at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy

Answer (score 0):

This means when there is any falsy value like `null` or `undefined` or 0  in `_key.which` then it should be initialized with `_key.key`.

You can see it as shortcut for:

```
var _keypressed = _key.which;
if (!_keypressed) {
    _keypressed = _key.key;
}
```

Comment: Not just null or undefined, all falsy values

Comment: or 0 or '' or false too

Answer (score 0):

It provides a fallback to the var. If the first option is false, null or undefined, the var will be set with the second value