# My if/else is not working like it should

Tags: javascript, if-statement

My if else is not working like it should. I have 1 `if` 1 `else if` and 1 `else`. When the function runs it executes the if even if the condition is "false".

Here is the JavaScript:

```js
function onSearch(){
 
 var site;
  
 document.getElementById('bar').value = site;
 
 //These are not the actuall links since it's not the actuall code.
  
    if (site === "Google" || "google"){
 
      location.href = "http://www.google.com";  

    }
 
  
  
 else if (site === "Youtube" || "youtube"){
 
      location.href = "http://www.youtube.com";
 
 }

  
  
 else{
 document.getElementById("SearchFail01").innerHTML =
 "The country " + site + " does not exist";
 }
```

```html
<!-- Here is the HTML -->
  
<input type='search' id='bar' list='countries' placeholder='Search..'>

<p id="SearchFail01"></p>
```

Comment: Use == instead of "==="?

Comment: `site === "Google" || site === "google"` but best would be a single `site.toLowerCase() === "google"`

Comment: Should probably just downcase the site's received

Comment: You need to have the `` side === ...   on both side of the ``||.  Otherwise it checks the second one as a simple boolean.  But since 'youtube' is not true, it will always evaluate as false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Javascript, a string in a conditional statement is considered True. The "||" operator won't work the way you're trying to make it work so you'll have to spell it out.

```
if (site === "Google" || site === "google"){

  location.href = "http://www.google.com";      

}



else if (site === "Youtube" || site === "youtube"){

  location.href = "http://www.youtube.com";

}



else{
document.getElementById("SearchFail01").innerHTML =
"The country " + site + " does not exist";
}
```

edit:

I also noticed this line:

```
document.getElementById('bar').value = site;
```

should probably be flipped if you want to assign bar's value to site

```
site = document.getElementById('bar').value;
```

Comment: Thanks i changed the `document.getElementById('bar').value = site;`      to                                                                                                             `site = document.getElementById('bar').value;` and now it properly fetches the value of the input!

Answer (score 1):

The [double pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802055/what-does-the-construct-x-x-y-mean) doesn't work like you expect. This is how it is supposed to be used.

`var foo = someVar || "foo";` not to be used inside an if like that

In your case you could simply [lowercase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) the site and use a single `===`

```
if (site.toLowerCase() === "google") {
    location.href = "http://www.google.com";        
}
```

Comment: Never tried that but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to consider using a switch.

```
switch (site) {
    case "Google":
    case "google":
        location.href = "http://www.google.com";
        break;
    case "Youtube":
    case "youtube":
        location.href = "http://www.youtube.com";
        break;
    default:
        document.getElementById("SearchFail01").innerHTML = "The country " + site + " does not exist";
    break;
}
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work but the if/else is now working so thanks for trying to help!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have a logic problem if your **if** and your **endif** conditions.

When you have 2 or more conditions in JavaScript, separated with the **OR** (||), or **AND** (&&) operators you need to make the comparisons in each condition.

Instead of:

```js
if (site === "Google" || "google"){
```

you have to write:

```js
if (site === "Google" || site === "google"){
```

And instead of:

```
else if (site === "Youtube" || "youtube"){
```

you have to write:

```js
else if (site === "Youtube" || site === "youtube"){
```

Hope this is helpful!

Cheers mate!

Comment: Thanks for the help!