# How to reduce this Cyclomatic complexity in this JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cyclomatic-complexity

I'm building a simple ETL tool using Node.js. So, I get one json object and manipulate to another object. However, after running through Lint, I get

> 18:1  warning  Function 'format' has a complexity of 5  complexity

This is the example of the code. I wish there's some JavaScript magic I could use.

```
  if (rawObj.attr1 && rawObj.attr2) {
    formattedObj.attr2 = rawObj.attr1;
  }
  if (rawObj.attr3) {
    formattedObj.otherAttr = rawObj.attr3;
  }
  if (rawObj.attr4) {
    formattedObj.otherAttr4 = rawObj.attr4;
  }
  formattedObj.rank = index + 1;

  if (rawObj.attr5) {
    formattedObj.otherAttr5 = rawObj.attr5;
  }
```

basically, it's just checking if the property is `undefined` or not. Then sets the property.

Comment: Abstract out the copy? Use a general purpose transformation library?

Comment: Not sure how your complexity is measured, but you can inline your if statements using the ternary operator so that variable assignment always takes place, like so: `formattedObj.attr2 = rawObj.attr1 && rawObj.attr2 ? rawObj.attr1 : undefined;`. There are other ways to decrease your complexity, but a general solution would limit you somewhat.

Comment: Would something like this work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802055/what-does-the-construct-x-x-y-mean

Comment: @jedd.ahyoung That doesn't change complexity, it just rewrites it. The same conditions exist.

Comment: @DaveNewton Then, depending on your transformations, there's nothing you can do. If it's a one-to-one mapping (like rawObj.attr5) you can simply remove the if statement, as you'll be assigning `undefined` to an already undefined variable - that would solve your complexity issue. For cases like the first, though, Ithere is not a way, as you'll always have that conditional somewhere in your code.

Comment: Also - note that the way you have things now - you'll be tripped up by falsy values. You may want to specify `== null` or something like that depending on what you're looking for. (An empty string, or `0`, etc, will cause your conditionals to fail.)

Comment: @jedd.ahyoung Correct. Swapping conditional constructs doesn't affect cyclomatic complexity, only reducing complexity does.

Answer (score 2):

You're repeating yourself. Use a loop instead:

```
var props = [
    {from: "attr3", to:"otherAttr"},
    {from: "attr4", to:"otherAttr4"},
    {from: "attr5", to:"otherAttr5"}
];
if (rawObj.attr2)
    props.push({from: "attr1", to:"attr2"});

props.forEach(function(p) {
    if (rawObj[p.from])
        formattedObj[p.to] = rawObj[p.from];
});
formattedObj.rank = index + 1;
```

Comment: Does this actually reduce the complexity? For static analysis, perhaps, but I don't think this actually works....unless I don't fully understand the definition.

Comment: @jedd.ahyoung What do you think does not work about it?