# OR operator with real numbers

Tags: javascript, logical-operators

Why is the mid number result of this statement?

```
(0 || 0.571428571428571 || 1) == 0.571428571428571
```

How the comparsion works?

---

Well. Looks like stupid question. For those who works in php where this statement has a different result could be helpfull to know that **JS will return number** instead bool.

Comment: What did you expect the result to be, and why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the construct \`x = x || y;\` mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802055/what-does-the-construct-x-x-y-mean)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`||` is a [short-circuiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) operator. It evaluates its left-hand operand, and returns that if it's truthy, otherwise it evaluates and returns its right-hand operator. When you have a sequence of `||` operators, it performs this left-to-right, returning the first truthy value (or the last value if none are truthy).

In your example, `0` is falsey, so `0.571428571428571` is the first truthy value, and it's returned.

Comment: Barmar thnk you. The problem was i switched from PHP to JS. in PHP is result 1 or 0. I expected the same, not the number.

Comment: In PHP, the logical operators always return a boolean result, rather than one of the arguments.

Answer (score 3):

Your expression is interpreted as

```
((0 || 0.571428571428571) || 1)
```

The result of the first `||` is truthy, so that's the result of the overall expression. That's how `||` works: the result is the left-hand operand if it's truthy, or else the right-hand operand.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this lies in the fact that 0 is considered a false value while non-zero numbers are considered true.

Since `||` and `&&` will short circuit and return as soon as it knows the outcome. For OR expressions this means that the first truthy value will be returned. For AND expressions it means the first false value is returned:

```
(true && true && 0 && true) === 0
(false && false && 1) === 1

(false || false || 1 || false) === 1
(false || false || 0) === 0
```

Since the first value in your expression is a falsey value, it is not returned but the floating point is a truthy value, so it is returned.