# Google script/JavaScript: What does this do following an object: (Objectname || {});

Tags: javascript

I am reading a book on Google Scripting, and don't understand the syntax or what the last line accomplishes after the function closes (between here). Am I to read that as: Objectname or empty object brackets? What might this possibly mean?

```
var Objectname = (function (parameter) {

  //additional scripting omitted here

  return parameter;

}) (Objectname || {});  //I don't understand the purpose of this final statement: (Objectname || {})
```

Comment: Lots of duplicates, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/2802055/218196 . Please use the search!

Comment: I guess that's because people mostly use google for searching anywhere instead of appropriate search engine and since google doesn't accept special punctuation questions like this one arise. I could swear I've seen that question asked 2 days ago.

Comment: Stackoverflow's search engine also ignores "special symbols"? Edit, cannot post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%22||%20{}%22)

Comment: @vove: Stack Overflow's used to be better at this. Either way, because of that it often helps to search with the name of the operator or a description of how it looks like: [`[javascript] double pipe`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+double+pipe), [`[javascript] boolean "OR" operator`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+boolean+%22OR%22+operator)

Answer (score 0):

The `()` calls the function which precedes it.

`Objectname || {}` is the argument list.

`||` is an OR operator. If the left hand side is true, it evaluates as the left hand side, otherwise it evaluates as the right hand side.

---

If you remove all the shorthand from this you end up something roughly (it creates an additional global variable) along the lines of:

```
function initialise_objectname(parameter) {
    // ...
    return parameter;
}
var Objectname;
if (Objectname) {
    Objectname = initialise_objectname(Objectname);
} else {
    Objectname = initialise_objectname({});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

```
var hello = false;
var test = hello || 123;

//test == 123 because hello == false
```

Example 2:

```
var hello = true;
var test = hello || 123;

//test == true because hello == true
```

Makes sense? If the left hand side is true, it will set it to that, otherwise it will pick the other side.