# How can I stop pass by reference an object stored in prototype?

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

Can I define an object as a prototype member? If yes then how can I stop the call by reference of an instantiated object?

```
function MediaUser (){
}

MediaUser.prototype.oThumb = {sUrl: 'noImage.png'};

var oMediaUser = new MediaUser();
var oMediaUser2 = new MediaUser();

oMediaUser.oThumb.sUrl = "a.png";

console.log(oMediaUser2.oThumb.sUrl); // prints a.png
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything you define in prototype is shared by all objects. You have to put that inside the constructor if you want it to be different for all instances:

```js
function MediaUser (){
  this.oThumb = {sUrl: 'noImage.png'}
}

var oMediaUser = new MediaUser();
var oMediaUser2 = new MediaUser();

oMediaUser.oThumb.sUrl = "a.png";

console.log(oMediaUser2.oThumb.sUrl); // prints noImage.png
```

Comment: so @Gothdo, anytime if I want to add an object inside another object, I always have to put it as an instance member rather than prototype member ?

Answer (score 0):

In fact when you are looking for separate value for each object , get rid of thet prototype property altogether

```
function MediaUser (url){
 this.sUrl = url || 'noImage.png';
}


var oMediaUser = new MediaUser("a.png");
var oMediaUser2 = new MediaUser();

console.log(oMediaUser.sUrl); // prints a.png

console.log(oMediaUser2.sUrl); // prints noImage.png
```

Comment: Don't use the `a = a || b` construct, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802055/what-does-the-construct-x-x-y-mean/34707750#34707750

Comment: @Gothdo The construct is fine as long as you know the pitfalls. Not using it would show a lack of understanding in many cases just like always using `===` for nothing.

Comment: @plalx Well, always using `===` is considered a good practice.