# understanding OR operator in nodejs

Tags: node.js, node-webkit

Hello I have some problem understanding the following code related to node.js.

```
var config = {
    local: {
        mode: 'local',
        port: 3000
    },
    staging: {
        mode: 'staging',
        port: 4000
    },
    production: {
        mode: 'production',
        port: 5000
    }
}
module.exports = function(mode) {
    return config[mode || process.argv[2] || 'local'] || config.local;
}
```

I cannot understand

```
return config[mode || process.argv[2] || 'local'] || config.local;
```

this part. **What and how will the OR operator work and return**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this one?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802055/what-does-the-construct-x-x-y-mean

Answer (score 0):

It is equivalent to:

```
var r;

if(mode && config[mode]) {
    r = config[mode];
} else if(process.argv[2] && config[process.argv[2]]) {
    r = config[process.argv[2]];
} else if(config['local']) {
    r = config['local'];
} else {
    r = config.local;
}
return r;
```

Note that `config['local']` and `config.local` would return the same value, so the last part (`|| config.local`) is useless.

Answer (score 0):

```
return config[mode || process.argv[2] || 'local'] || config.local;
```

EDIT: In the above code everything within the enclosing square bracket will be evaluated prior to attempting to access config[key].

Comment: thanks ... it is working like that so I think this is correct. don't know why someone gave you a negative one vote...

Comment: I suspect it was downvoted because it is incorrect. The key expression is evaluated and a single lookup into `config` is performed. The equivalent is: `var temp = mode || process.argv[2] || 'local'; return config[temp] || config.local;`