# JS Sort By Multiple constraints

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a array of elements as follows:

```
var a = [
  <tr data-order=​"0" data-time=​"840">​…​</tr>​,
  <tr data-order=​"0" data-time=​"60">​…​</tr>​,
  <tr data-order=​"1" data-time=​"10">​…​</tr>​,
  <tr data-order=​"2" data-time=​"20">​…​</tr>​,
  <tr data-order=​"3" data-time=​"15">​…​</tr>​,
  <tr data-order=​"4" data-time=​"40">​…​</tr>​,
  <tr data-order=​"5" data-time=​"30">​…​</tr>​,
  <tr data-order=​"6" data-time=​"1320">​…​</tr>​
]
```

I want to sort them according to **data-order** as well as **data-time**. What I'm able to achieve is:

```
a.sort(function(m, n) {
  return parseInt( $(m).attr("data-order") ) - parseInt( $(n).attr("data-order") )
});
```

That gives me elements sorted by **date-order**, but for same date order, I want it to be sorted by **date-time**.

How can I sort by multiple attributes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case the difference is zero( i.e, values are same) do the second comparison. You can use [logical OR (`||`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()) for reduce the number of lines. For getting data-* attribute use [`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) method and there is no need to parse it since we are taking the difference.

```
a.sort(function(m, n) {
  return $(m).data('order') - $(n).data('order') || $(m).data('time') - $(n).data('time');
});
```

---

Refer : [What does the construct x = x || y mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802055/what-does-the-construct-x-x-y-mean)