# What does this specific line of code mean/do in Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, object

I'm practicing my coding and I'm still kind of new. While looking for solutions to practice problems I see this kind of code used in loops and I'm curious what this line of code does.

```
counter[string[i]] = (counter[string[i]] || 0) + 1;
```

here it is in the full code that is used to count most occured character in a string if this helps

```
var string  = "355385",
    counter = {};

for (var i = 0, len = string.length; i < len; i += 1) {
    counter[string[i]] = (counter[string[i]] || 0) + 1;
}

var biggest = -1, number;
for (var key in counter) {
    if (counter[key] > biggest) {
        biggest = counter[key];
        number = key;
    }
}

console.log(number);
```

Comment: What specific part do you not understand?

Comment: Potentially a duplicate of [What does the construct x = x || y mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2802055/218196)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is basically saying

If `counter[string[i]]` is falsy (undefined, 0, empty string, null etc) use `0` to add to `1` otherwise use its existing value to add to 1 and make this addition the new value for `counter[string[i]]`

It is using the logical OR operator `||`

See [JavaScript OR (||) variable assignment explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100758/javascript-or-variable-assignment-explanation)