# Can some please explain this JavaScript for loop from Browserstack?

Tags: javascript, browserstack

I'm using BrowserStack to run my test automation - there is a config example on their site to set up 'commonCapabilities'.

I know this is basic JS but what's the use for the double pipe within this for loop?

```
// Code to support common capabilities
exports.config.multiCapabilities.forEach(function(caps){
  for(var i in exports.config.commonCapabilities) caps[i] = caps[i] || exports.config.commonCapabilities[i];
});
```

The full config:

https://www.browserstack.com/automate/protractor

```
exports.config = {
  'seleniumAddress': 'http://hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub',

  'commonCapabilities': {
    'browserstack.user': 'xxxx',
    'browserstack.key': 'xxxx'
  },

  'multiCapabilities': [{
    'browserName': 'Chrome'
  },{
    'browserName': 'Safari'
  },{
    'browserName': 'Firefox'
  },{
    'browserName': 'IE'
  }]
};

// Code to support common capabilities
exports.config.multiCapabilities.forEach(function(caps){
  for(var i in exports.config.commonCapabilities) caps[i] = caps[i] || exports.config.commonCapabilities[i];
});
```

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802055/what-does-the-construct-x-x-y-mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an expression that is more easily read like so:

```
for(var i in exports.config.commonCapabilities) {
  caps[i] = (caps[i] || exports.config.commonCapabilities[i]);
}
```

Which means return `caps[i]` if it can be converted to true; otherwise, return `exports.config.commonCapabilities[i]`. If `caps[i]` is undefined, as that's a falsey value, it'll set the variable to `exports.config.commonCapabilities[i]`. It's a way of making sure each is defined, otherwise fallback to some standard config.

Answer (score 0):

this part: `caps[i] = caps[i] || exports.config.commonCapabilities[i]` basically says if `caps[i]` is not defined (or null, false, 0, NaN, ""(not a falsey value)) run than `caps[i] = exports.config.commonCapabilities[i]`.

for example:

```
var x = x || "value"
```

which has the same functionality as

```
if(x){/*nothing as it is already assigned*/} else {x = "value"}
```

> If the first value is false, it checks the second value. If it's true, it returns true and if it's false, it returns false.
>   If the first value is true, it always returns true, no matter what the second value is. from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802055/what-does-the-construct-x-x-y-mean#answer-34707750)