# A code puzzles me in koa2

Tags: node.js, koa

Here is the code

```
let name1 = "nobody"
let name2 = ctx.request.query.name || name1;
```

This code is equivalent to

```
let name2 = ctx.request.query.name?ctx.request.query.name:name1
```

I thought here `||` is `or`, and is this a function in `ctx.request.query`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the construct x = x || y mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802055/what-does-the-construct-x-x-y-mean)

Comment: See the [2nd answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34707750/1765851) in that question, which explains the behaviour very well.